# Where is Python's "best ASCII for this Unicode" database?

Tags: python, unicode, ascii

I have some text that uses Unicode punctuation, like left double quote, right single quote for apostrophe, and so on, and I need it in ASCII. Does Python have a database of these characters with obvious ASCII substitutes so I can do better than turning them all into "?" ?

Comment: People who find this might be interested in [What is the best way to remove accents in a Python unicode string?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/517923/562769)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

[Unidecode](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) looks like a complete solution. It converts fancy quotes to ascii quotes, accented latin characters to unaccented and even attempts transliteration to deal with characters that don't have ASCII equivalents. That way your users don't have to see a bunch of ? when you had to pass their text through a legacy 7-bit ascii system.

```
>>> from unidecode import unidecode
>>> print unidecode(u"\u5317\u4EB0")
Bei Jing
```

http://www.tablix.org/~avian/blog/archives/2009/01/unicode_transliteration_in_python/

Comment: Hm.. german umlauts are converted to their base character instead of e.g. ö=oe, ä=ae, etc.

Comment: @ThiefMaster are those equivalents true across all languages? Maybe Unidecode is going for the lowest common denominator.

Comment: Unidecode most certainly goes for the language-independent solution. For a German-centric solution, convert applicable charecters manually (`s/ö/oe/`, etc.) before cleaning up the rest with `unidecode`.

Comment: Indeed, in Finnish for example, while `ä -> a`, `ö -> o` is outright wrong, it is still preferable to `ae` and `oe`

Answer (score 27):

In my original answer, I also suggested `unicodedata.normalize`. However, I decided to test it out and it turns out it doesn't work with Unicode quotation marks. It does a good job translating accented Unicode characters, so I'm guessing `unicodedata.normalize` is implemented using the `unicode.decomposition` function, which leads me to believe it probably can only handle Unicode characters that are combinations of a letter and a diacritical mark, but I'm not really an expert on the Unicode specification, so I could just be full of hot air...

In any event, you can use `unicode.translate` to deal with punctuation characters instead. The `translate` method takes a dictionary of Unicode ordinals to Unicode ordinals, thus you can create a mapping that translates Unicode-only punctuation to ASCII-compatible punctuation:

```
'Maps left and right single and double quotation marks'
'into ASCII single and double quotation marks'
>>> punctuation = { 0x2018:0x27, 0x2019:0x27, 0x201C:0x22, 0x201D:0x22 }
>>> teststring = u'\u201Chello, world!\u201D'
>>> teststring.translate(punctuation).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
'"hello, world!"'
```

You can add more punctuation mappings if needed, but I don't think you necessarily need to worry about handling every single Unicode punctuation character. If you *do* need to handle accents and other diacritical marks, you can still use `unicodedata.normalize` to deal with those characters.

Answer (score 23):

Interesting question.

Google helped me find [this page](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/unicode-to-ascii) which descibes using the [unicodedata module](http://effbot.org/librarybook/unicodedata.htm) as the following:

```
import unicodedata
unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', title).encode('ascii','ignore')
```