# GAE: TypeError: character mapping must return integer, None or unicode

Tags: python, google-app-engine, unicode, oauth-2.0, dropbox

I'm trying to get [site in a dropbox](https://github.com/Japanuspus/Site-in-a-Dropbox) working mainly to figure out how to use dropbox on appengine.

the python:
c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine>python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\_webapp25.py", line 701, in __call__
    handler.get(*groups)
  File "C:\youiestsiteinadropbox\siteinadropbox\handlers\dropboxhandlers.py", line 38, in new_f
    f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\youiestsiteinadropbox\siteinadropbox\handlers\dropboxhandlers.py", line 65, in get
    self.dropbox_auth_callback(self.site)
  File "C:\youiestsiteinadropbox\siteinadropbox\handlers\dropboxhandlers.py", line 118, in dropbox_auth_callback
    access_token = models.Site.dropbox_auth.obtain_access_token(token, "")
  File "C:\youiestsiteinadropbox\dropbox\auth.py", line 177, in obtain_access_token
    self.oauth_request.sign_request(self.signature_method_hmac_sha1, self.consumer, token)
  File "C:\youiestsiteinadropbox\oauth\oauth.py", line 259, in sign_request
    self.build_signature(signature_method, consumer, token))
  File "C:\youiestsiteinadropbox\oauth\oauth.py", line 263, in build_signature
    return signature_method.build_signature(self, consumer, token)
  File "C:\youiestsiteinadropbox\oauth\oauth.py", line 634, in build_signature
    hashed = hmac.new(key, raw, sha)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\hmac.py", line 133, in new
    return HMAC(key, msg, digestmod)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\hmac.py", line 72, in __init__
    self.outer.update(key.translate(trans_5C))
TypeError: character mapping must return integer, None or unicode
```

The last call made inside the app is:

File "C:\youiestsiteinadropbox\siteinadropbox\handlers\dropboxhandlers.py", line 118, in dropbox_auth_callback
    access_token = models.Site.dropbox_auth.obtain_access_token(token, "")

Not having much success converting this part to unicode. Any ideas or other pointers on how to get started with dropbox on appengine? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't ever used siteinadropbox, but the end cause of this error is that the `key` variable from the last is a `unicode` object, when the code is expecting it to be a `str` object. Not a particularly helpful message, I know.

I checked out the siteinadropbox code and checked to see where that `key` value is coming from, and unless there are shenanigans going on somewhere, it will only be unicode when your `dropbox.auth.Authenticator` instance's `self.consumer.secret` is unicode or when `token.secret` from `dropbox_auth_callback` is unicode. I don't see with a cursory examination how either of those could happen. Did you happen to pass in a custom `config` dict when creating your `Authenticator`, or did you follow the pattern of using `Authenticator.load_config`, as is done in the `siteinadropbox/models/site.py` and `test/dbtools.py` examples?

Comment: Thanks for looking through the code and for the reply. Nope, no changes, pretty much out of the box. Though I'm taking a closer look at that test/dbtools.py

Comment: If it was me, then, I'd start adding good old-fashioned `print`s inside the siteinadropbox code to see where the unicodeness was coming from. For example, '`print repr(key)`' right before line 634 in oath/oath.py, and '`print repr(consumer.secret), repr(token.secret)`' right before line 259 in the same file.

Comment: on ln 634.. u'y5ddw9mz4n7s4w8&bzy7lgx8tib6p61' Status: 500 Internal Server Error Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Cache-Control: no-cache Set-Cookie: token= Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT Content-Length: 1783 .... thought u' means unicode but can't find that anywhere now.. edit: I realize now this is probably totally wrong.

Comment: I don't think I follow.. the `u'y5ddw9mz4n7s4w8&bzy7lgx8tib6p61'` is indeed a unicode object. The main first question is whether it came from `consumer.secret` or `token.secret` earlier. (Note: you may not want to paste the actual values for those, since it may give someone else access to your dropbox!)

Comment: That's probably because I'm a bot confused. that bit came with the trace in the browser when running the project locally. A different error happens on gae, basically dropbox tells it it's unauthorized which seems to fit the bill. Thanks again for helping, checking the origin.

Comment: return binascii.b2a_base64(hashed.digest())[:-1] .. that doesn't look like it returns unicode does it.. what's happening here?

Comment: hashed = hmac.new(key, raw, hashlib.sha1) and hashed = hmac.new(key, raw, sha) both return error as it's looking.

Comment: Right, the code is not ever reaching that b2a_base64 call, and it's expected that both hashlib.sha1 and sha would fail to calculate a hash of a unicode object (since they don't know how you want to encode it to bytes). The problem, whatever it is, is coming earlier- something is causing the key object to be unicode, when it should be str (bytes).

Comment: shouldn't it be possible to losslessly convert it to a string if it should be a string to begin with? when i try [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207457/convert-unicode-to-string-in-python-containing-extra-symbols) i get nowhere. I'm thinking this code is just to old and there's some platform issue happening I can't figure out. I'm now looking into flask for appengine as a way to talk to dropbox.. though i'm afraid I'll just find more of the same. Any ideas on how to get going with dropbox on appengine? posting that as a question..

Comment: you can't change unicode to bytes without specifying a *way* to change it. it's like integers; to store them in bytes, you have to know if you're using big-endian or little-endian, how many bits per value, etc. And it might be meaningless in your case just to guess an encoding, because it's not clear why one of the source values was unicode in the first place. That's the part to fix, not band-aid over it by trying to force the (possibly garbage) value back to bytes.

Answer (score 0):

I modified hmac.py, convert key to str object if it's unicode before tranlate called, and it works.

```
    # hmac.py
       ...
    71 key = key + chr(0) * (blocksize - len(key))
    72 if type(key) == unicode:
    73     key = key.encode()
    74 self.outer.update(key.translate(trans_5C))
       ...
```