# converting tweets to string in Python

Tags: python, twitter, unicode, tweets, tweepy

I'm using tweepy to collect random tweets,
and I want to filter out non-alphanumeric tweets.

But in order to do the checking, I first need to convert the tweets to string.
For example,

```
from tweepy import StreamListener
....

class sListener(StreamListener):
       def on_status(self,status):
            ....
            text = str(status.text)
            if not isAlphanumeric(text):
                ......
```

However, using str() to convert the tweet to string itself results in an error if the tweet is non-ascii with the following message:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character
```

So I'm stuck in a loop where I need to convert to string to filter non-ascii, but I can't convert to string because of non-ascii....

I don't even know what data type tweets are...

Could anyone please help me out?

Comment: Did you try this? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1207479/1984421)

Comment: If you do not want non-ascii tweets, why not just skip those that won't convert using `str()`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your tweets encoding is not `ascii`

Try

```
text = unicode(status.text)
```

instead of

```
text = str(status.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
text = status.text.encode('utf8')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in the past. See if this works:

```
tweetText = status.text.encode("utf-8")
tweetText = unicode(tweetText, errors='ignore')
```