# exclude unicode from split() of db.get result

Tags: python

The result below for  x.split() is what I want because there is no unicode in the result.

```
server:~ brian$ python
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jul 31 2011, 19:30:53) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = 'M Y'
>>> x.split()
['M', 'Y']
```

But in my application using `db.get` as below, the result for `choices` is `[u'M', u'Y']` instead, when `'choices'` = `'M Y'`.

```
def post(self, blog_id):
        blog = db.get(db.Key.from_path('Blogs', blog_id))
    n = Reminders(parent=blog, purpose=self.request.get('purpose'),
                  choices=self.request.get('choices').split())
        n.put()
```

How can I get my desired result?

This question is different from the other one because it seems as if google-app-engine or  python2.7 forces the u'' around each element of the sequence that is split. I have tried using `.encode('ascii','ignore')` also, but to no avail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python .split() without 'u](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14664209/python-split-without-u)

Comment: How does that affect your program?...as I believe it is advised to deal with unicode strings, and since you are dealing with Python2.7, it is natural that you get `u'M'` and `u'Y'` as output...as they were treaded as unicode string in your `db` objects.

Comment: And it seems to me you are working with GAE DB?...am I wrong?

Comment: It affects my program because I want to include the results as one of the parameters/arguments to a javascript function. The js function chokes on that argument. I have been  [fiddling with it here](https://jsfiddle.net/sqtqtkxb/9/) If you go there, try double clicking on the "M". Then change the input to the function to include u'.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [encode](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#python-2-x-s-unicode-support) function.

Example:

```
In [1]: x= u'M Y'

In [2]: x
Out[2]: u'M Y'

In [3]: x.split()
Out[3]: [u'M', u'Y']

In [4]: x.encode('utf8').split()
Out[4]: ['M', 'Y']
```

In your code, add the `encode` function before you split:

```
n = Reminders(parent=blog, purpose=self.request.get('purpose'),
     choices=self.request.get('choices').encode('utf8').split())
```

Comment: That looked promising, but would not work. I even tried placing `.encode('utf8')` differently or with more parens, but either get the same result which still includes `u'`, or get an error message that lists do not have .split()s.

Comment: In that case, you might want to do something like `n=[s.encode('utf8') for s in Reminders(parent=blog, purpose=self.request.get('purpose'), choices=self.request.get('choices').encode('utf8').split())]` which will take the previous unicode list and will create a new one without the `u`

Comment: I am getting the error `TypeError: 'Reminders' object is not iterable`.

Comment: It seems like Reminders is a class that you implemented yourself. In that case, you have to make it iterable. In order to do this you should implement the `__iter__` function and the `next` function. For more information, take look on the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151/how-to-make-class-iterable)

Comment: That sounds like it might be a good alternative. If you look at the comments for the question itself, Iron Fist  suggested that Reminders is part of GAE's db  models. Although I neglected to confirm Iron Fist's "suggestion" it was correct and my code includes `class Reminders(db.Model):`. So I am not sure that it is possible to implement the `__iter__` function in this case. Anyway, for now, as you  can tell by seeing my  "answer", I have answered the question by dodging it altogether.

Comment: An alternative would be to do this process in two steps. The first step is to get the reminders the way you did. Seems like it returns a list of unicode strings (`n` in your original code). String is an utterable object so you can generate another list without the unicode part: `lst = [s for s in n]`

Answer (score 0):

In my case the answer was simple, just do the split() in javascript instead of in python. That way the `u'...'`s never get generated.