# u character appears within a regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

I have some lines of code which extracts email addresses from a pdf file.

```
 for page in pdf.pages:
      pdf = page.extractText()
      # print elpdf
      r = re.compile(r'[\w\-][\w\-\.]+@[\w\-][\w\-\.]+[a-zA-Z]{1,4}')
      results = r.findall(pdf)
      Listemail.append(results)
      print(Listemail[0:])
 pdf.stream.close()
```

Unfortunately, after running the code I have noticed that results are not completely fine as it appears a 'u' character every time a match is found:

```
[[u'testuser1@training.local']]
[[u'testuser2@training.local']]
```

Does anybody know haow to avoid that character appearing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have noted, this is not a bug, but a feature.

If what you want are non-unicode encoded strings, you can convert the text from unicode to something more palatable. This StackOverflow Q/A cover the subject:

[Convert a Unicode string to a string in Python (containing extra symbols)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207457/convert-unicode-to-string-in-python-containing-extra-symbols)

I've run into this before and in some use cases, it can be problematic, as you will then encounter issues where a method expects a non-unicode string and breaks. :)

Example solutions from that link:

```
>>> a=u'aaa'
>>> a
u'aaa'
>>> a.encode('ascii','ignore')
'aaa'
>>> a.encode('utf8','ignore')
'aaa'
>>> str(a)
'aaa'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not a problem. That `u` prefacing your strings just indicates that it's a Python `unicode` string. [See this documentation.](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) Unless you're doing anything crazy with them that for some reason requires your strings not be unicode, I don't see how this could be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

These are [unicode strings](http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings), you don't need to avoid them unless you have some real problems.