# Splitting a String and Assigning it Variables

Tags: python, string, list, split

Im taking info from my school grade site and its coming out as a long string this is the output:

```
[u'--']
[u'B', u'84']
[u'--']
[u'A-', u'90']
[u'--']
[u'C+', u'79']
[u'--']
[u'A', u'95']
[u'--']
[u'B', u'82']
[u'--']
[u'B', u'81']
```

Im using this to get the out put

```
for cell in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".grid tr a[href$='fg=S2']"):
    gradesList = cell.text.split('\n')
    print gradesList
```

i want to assign each of the grades a variable but im not sure how to get them all to separate to each variable

Comment: You can treat each one as a separate variable in that you can access the elements of the list `gradesList[0]` for example.

Comment: if i `print gradesList[0]` it print just the letters for the grades but they are still all together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `.split` call in your loop returns a different number of elements depending on the HTML tag you're looking at. If there isn't any way to filter out those bad tags, here's a clean way with destructuring assignment, skipping the element if necessary:

```
for cell in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".grid tr a[href$='fg=S2']"):
    gradesList = cell.text.split('\n')
    if len(gradesList) < 2:
        continue

    letter_grade, score = gradesList

    # Use variables...
```

If you can figure out a way to avoid the elements with only "--" as text (extra CSS class? content filter with your parser library?) we can get a nice list comprehension:

```
grade_elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".grid tr a[href$='fg=S2']")
grades = [g.text.split('\n') for g in grade_elements]
```

Comment: See my updated answer. If you have a way of filtering out the elements with only '--', you can get a very simple solution.

Comment: i got the grades but there like this `[u'B', u'84']

Comment: @Christian - python unicode (http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html). If you need ascii (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207457/convert-unicode-to-string-in-python-containing-extra-symbols)