# suppose output python list as javascript list in html, but the char "&#39;" is printed

Tags: javascript, python, json, web.py

I have a python list: categoriesPython, which is ['Firefox 2.0', 'Firefox 3.0', 'Firefox 3.5', 'Firefox 3.6', 'Firefox 4.0'],
I did(I am using web.py):

```
data: {
       name: 'Firefox versions',
       categories: $categoriesPython,
       version: [0.20, 0.83, 1.58, 13.12, 5.43]
      }
```

I expected to get:

```
data: {
       name: 'Firefox versions',
       categories: ['Firefox 2.0', 'Firefox 3.0', 'Firefox 3.5', 'Firefox 3.6', 'Firefox 4.0'],
       version: [0.20, 0.83, 1.58, 13.12, 5.43]
      }
```

However, I got:

```
data: {
       name: 'Firefox versions',
       categories: [&#39;Firefox 2.0&#39;, &#39;Firefox 3.0&#39;, &#39;Firefox 3.5&#39;, &#39;Firefox 3.6&#39;, &#39;Firefox 4.0&#39;],
       version: [0.20, 0.83, 1.58, 13.12, 5.43]
      }
```

1. Because data is Json format, there cannot be have any assign value, for example:

```
    data: {
       name: 'Firefox versions',
       categorieData.push('$categoriesPython');
       categories: categorieData,
       version: [0.20, 0.83, 1.58, 13.12, 5.43]
      }
```

also, I do not want to convert python list to javascript list, because the list have more than 200 value, if convert, there must be have more than 200 categorieData.push('$categoriesPython');, the code will be redundant.

How can I get the expected result?

Comment: It appears that something is incorrectly encoding `'` as `&#39;` (an HTML character reference.).

Comment: How are you creating the JSON?

Comment: I think you can use `$:categoriesPython`, try it and let us know.

Comment: use $:categoriesPython, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs on [Filtering](http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/templetor#filtering) it would appear that

```
$:categoriesPython
```

might do the trick

> By default, Templetor uses web.websafe filter to do HTML-encoding.
>
> render.hello("1 < 2") "Hello 1 < 2"
>
> To turnoff filter use : after $. For example:
>
> The following will not be html escaped. $:form.render()

Comment: It works, but I got: [u'Firefox 2.0', u'Firefox 3.0', u'Firefox 3.5', u'Firefox 3.6', u'Firefox 4.0'], how can I remove u prefix?

Comment: Yes, I fixed:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207457/convert-unicode-to-string-in-python-containing-extra-symbols

Comment: BTW, you don't need to do what is in that answer to convert (your examples) to none-Unicode strings.  Just do `str(item)` where item is your current Unicode string.

Comment: I did $str(item) in the html part, but I got "global name 'str' is not defined"...