# I have a dictionary with a value that is as a list of unicode strings, I would like to get them as a string?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a dictionary that its value is a list and the values of the list are unicode , I would like to get them as a string , how do I go about geting them.

```
d = {'1':[u'06'],'2':[u'02',u'03',u'05',u'10']}
```

output for key `'2'`:

```
02,03,05,10
```

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this link can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207457/convert-unicode-to-string-in-python-containing-extra-symbols

Comment: Can you give a simple example of your dictionary?  A list can not be used as a key.  Do you mean you have a value in your dictionary that is a list of unicode strings?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say value, its looks like this d = {'1':[u'06'],'2':[u'02',u'03',u'05',u'10']} it looks like that.

Comment: I want to be able to print the numbers. So print d['2'] would be 02,03,05,10

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Comment: It is, I just accepted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> d = {'1':[u'06'],'2':[u'02',u'03',u'05',u'10']}
>>> print ','.join([str(u) for u in d.get('2')])
02,03,05,10
```