# Extract xlrd package data extraction

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

When i am trying to extract the data from an xlsx files. I get the encoding details with the data as well.

Consider the code as shown below,

```
column_number = 0
column_headers = []
#column_headers = sheet.row_values(row_number)
while column_number <= sheet.ncols - 1:
    column_headers.append(sheet.cell(row_number, column_number).value)
    column_number+=1

return column_headers
```

output is,

```
[u'Rec#', u'Cyc#', u'Step', u'TestTime', u'StepTime', u'Amp-hr', u'Watt-hr', u'Amps', u'Volts', u'State', u'ES', u'DPt Time', u'ACR', u'DCIR']
```

I just want to extract the cell value which is the data without "u'" attached to it . How can i get just that ?

Comment: The main thing I have to ask is: **WHY** do you need the data without the `u`? I ask because it really sounds like you don't know what the `u` means. You haven't mentioned Unicode at all, you say you are getting "encoding details" when in fact the `u` means just the opposite, and in most cases a Unicode string compares equal to its "look-alike" ASCII-encoded byte string, so I'm really curious to find out what you need to get rid of the `u`s for.

Comment: it creates problems when i want to match some data from the cell directly to a harcoded value. Also, when i have to create a dictionary using this data and read it into a mongo collection, the mapping of data that comes from xlsx files and csv files are different. So this according to me xlrd specific. CSV python module does not do this. I hope i could help to resolve ur curiosity.

Comment: The Python `csv` module doesn't support Unicode, but **ALL** character data stored in an Excel file **is** Unicode. What hard-coded values are you trying to match? `u'foo'` is equal to `'foo'` in Python.

Comment: say the value of sheet.cell(4,0) is 3 and when i wanna match this with 3 . It doesnt really work.

Comment: Well, you accepted an answer already, but I'm still really confused. 3 is equal to 3 in Python. 3 is even equal to 3.0 in Python. So I have no idea why you are having any trouble.

Comment: the answer that i accepted works just the why i wanted. so the encode ascii ignore helps the 'u' disappear...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use string encoding to convert the `unicode` to `ascii`. So your updated code should be

```
column_headers.append((sheet.cell(row_number, column_number).value).encode('ascii','ignore'))
```

You can get the value by using `data.value` for the content of the field name. Also note that `integers` are imported as `floats` by default. So, you may end with with an additional `.0` in the end, which you can remove by typecasting the value by using `int(data.value)`.

Comment: It might work directly... but please take a look at the updated code in my question, it still gives me the same ouput. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:

```
print data.value
```

In the new code could you try this:

```
import unicodedata
...
output = []
for cell in column_headers:
    output.append(unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', cell))
return output
```

Please see this for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1207479/2168278

Comment: output.append(cell.value)
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'value'

Comment: I believe the last edit of my answer is correct; it works for me.