# How to convert unicode that I'm getting with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get Premier league table with this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url ="http://www.premierleague.com/en-gb.html"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'leagueTable'})
rows = table.findAll('tr')
data = [[td.text for td in tr.findAll("td")] for tr in rows]

for i in data:
    print i
```

Everything works perfect, except I get results in unicode. How to convert it into plain text?

Comment: Is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207457/convert-unicode-to-a-string-in-python-containing-extra-symbols

Comment: You can encode your Unicode stings. But why do yo want it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the line to  `text.encode("utf-8")`:

```
data = [[td.text.encode("utf-8") for td in tr.findAll("td")] for tr in rows]
or str(td.text)
```

Lots of info in the [BeautifulSoup docs](http://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)