# Remove regex pattern but keep whats in between python

Tags: python, regex

I have a paragraph that has multiple instances of it saying u'sometext in the middle'. Using python I would like  to be able to remove the u'' from the paragraph and leave sometext in the middle. There are multiple occurrences of this. How would I do this using regex?

Comment: `str = re.replace(u'(.+)','\1',str)` will do it for you.

Comment: It's probably just unicode, you can use `encode` to convert it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207457/convert-unicode-to-a-string-in-python-containing-extra-symbols

Comment: How do you generate this paragraph? Post your code. You shouldn't be having this problem in the first place.

Comment: Don't worry about this, its just showing it to you during development. When you write this paragraph to a file or print it, you will not see the `u''` part.

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight thanks that helped eliminate all those things

Comment: @user3456825 I've posted that as an answer so that you can accept and mark the question as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str = re.replace(u'(.+)','\1',str)` is what you want to get rid of those.