# Cannot convert from unicode

Tags: python, unicode

I have some unicode data in the following format:

```
 [(u"'goal','corner','rightfoot'", u'1'), (u"'goal','directfreekick','leftfoot'", u'1')
, (u"'goal','openplay','leftfoot'", u'2'), (u"'goal','openplay','rightfoot'", u'2'),
 (u"'miss','corner','header'", u'5'), (u"'miss','corner','rightfoot'", u'1'), 
(u"'miss','directfreekick','leftfoot'", u'1'), (u"'miss','directfreekick','rightfoot'", u'2'),
(u"'miss','openplay','header'", u'4'), (u"'miss','openplay','leftfoot'", u'14'), 
(u"'miss','openplay','rightfoot'", u'16')]
```

This is contained within a variable that for now I will call `var`. I want to convert this to a regular string using `str(var)`, however this does not seem to be having any effect.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: what do you call a regular string? are you looking to encode the unicode data into a particular format (UTF-8, ASCII,...)?

Comment: I don't think `str(var)` will do what you want, because it's effectively "turn this list into a string". You want "turn each element of each tuple in this list into a string", which is something else entirely. In any case, if `str` is literally having no effect at all, I suspect you're doing `str(var)` without assigning the result to anything. At least `var = str(var)` should have an observable effect.

Comment: It *is* a regular string. `str` is the weird type.

Comment: @kevin i have assigned the str conversion to another variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might do what you want:

```
var = [tuple(s.encode('ascii', 'replace') for s in t) for t in var]
```

Basically this loops over every tuple in var, takes every unicode string from that tuple and calls encode() on that unicode string.

But you should really read this: [Convert a Unicode string to a string in Python (containing extra symbols)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207457/convert-a-unicode-string-to-a-string-in-python-containing-extra-symbols)

Comment: hi, thanks for replying. that didnt work unfortunately.

Comment: Why not? What did/didn't it do?

Comment: My statement returns a new list (var doesn't change), I guess you need to assign it to var if you want to update that variable. Will change the answer.

Comment: sorry, that was a really dumb mistake on my part. i forgot to assign your expression to a variable. that works now, thanks a lot.