# Python - Convert unicode hex to string

Tags: python, django, unicode, utf-8, python-unicode

I am using [Readability Parser API](https://www.readability.com/developers/api/parser) to extract content from a web page. It is ok when the web page is in Latin character set, but when I extract article in Cyrillic, it ends up with the following:

```
<div>&#x412;&#x432;&#x43E;&#x441;&#x43A;&#x440;&#x435;&#x441;&#x435;&#x43D;&#x44C;</div>...etc
```

The interesting thing here is that the title of a web page is extracted correctly in Cyrillic, but not the content. My attempt was to do the following as it suggested in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1207479/1477118):

```
content = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', content).encode('ascii','ignore')
```

but it did not work. Could you tell me if there is a way to convert this string before saving to database?

Please let me know if the title of my question explains correctly what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way (Python 3.3):

```
>>> s='<div>&#x412;&#x432;&#x43E;&#x441;&#x43A;&#x440;&#x435;&#x441;&#x435;&#x43D;&#x44C;</div>'
>>> import html.parser
>>> h=html.parser.HTMLParser()
>>> h.unescape(s)
'<div>Ввоскресень</div>'
```

Python 2.7:

```
>>> s='<div>&#x412;&#x432;&#x43E;&#x441;&#x43A;&#x440;&#x435;&#x441;&#x435;&#x43D;&#x44C;</div>'
>>> import HTMLParser
>>> h=HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
>>> print(h.unescape(s))
<div>Ввоскресень</div>
```

P.S. I went to look for the documentation link and it looks like `unescape` isn't documented.  Here's a way without using an undocumented API:

```
>>> re.sub(r'&#x(.*?);',lambda x: chr(int(x.group(1),16)),s)
'<div>Ввоскресень</div>'
```

Per comment it looks finally documented (and moved) in Python 3.4:

- https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/html.html#html.unescape

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate it! I would only add that h.parser.unescape is deprecated(Python 3.5), so I used html.unescape().