# How to convert a string with unicode in it to unicode using python

Tags: python, excel, unicode

I am importing a bunch of data from excel using xlrd on python

I get all my data in string like this : text:u'L\xc9GENDE'

I manipulate these data and I try to put them back in excel (using xlsxwriter) and when I do, I get the same block of text text:u'L\xc9GENDE' instead of LÉGENDE.

What works for me :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
import xlsxwriter
import sys

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('hello.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
data = u'L\xc9GENDE'
worksheet.write('A1',data)
workbook.close()
```

this will work, I will get LÉGENDE in the A1 cell

but if I try to manipulate a string I have already to give me u'L\xc9GENDE', it will only show L\xc9GENDE in the A1 cell

---- EDIT ----
the code I use to retrieve data from excel

```
from xlrd import open_workbook

def grabexcelfile():
    wb = open_workbook('leg.xls',encoding_override='latin-1')    
    log = []
    txt = ''
    for s in wb.sheets():         
        for row in range(s.nrows):              
            values = []
            for col in range(s.ncols):
                 txt = str(s.cell(row,col))
                 txt.replace('-',' ',10) 
                 log.append(txt) 
    return log            

x = grabexcelfile()
print type(x[0]),x[0]
```

the print gives me :  text:u'L\xc9GENDE'

Comment: See something about `encode()`.

Comment: I have been on this for at least 5 hours. I tried encoding with latin-1 and utf-8 with no success

Comment: Did you try `encode('ascii','ignore')` ?

Comment: thank you for helping me, I did and it does not work for my problem

Comment: Show the code you are using to manipulate the string to give you `u'L\xc9GENDE'`.  We can't fix the code that doesn't work if you don't show the code that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to manipulate the text:u'L\xc9GENDE'  , I instead changed the type of var excel was given me with this :

```
from xlrd import open_workbook

def grabexcelfile():
    wb = open_workbook('leg.xls',encoding_override='latin-1')    
    log = []
    txt = ''
    for s in wb.sheets():         
        for row in range(s.nrows):              
            values = []
            for col in range(s.ncols):
                 #next line is changed
                 txt = sheet.cell(row,col).value
                 txt.replace('-',' ',10) 
                 log.append(txt) 
    return log            

x = grabexcelfile()
print type(x[0]),x[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
import unicodedata
data = u'L\xc9GENDE'
unicodedata.normalize('NFKD',data).encode('ascii','ignore')
```

You can refer here for more -> [Convert a Unicode string to a string in Python (containing extra symbols)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207457/convert-a-unicode-string-to-a-string-in-python-containing-extra-symbols)

Comment: That seems good if I have access to the string 'LÉGENDE' in python but when I import from excel I only have 'L\xc9GENDE', I went and checked the documentation on the website but I couldnt find anything to help me there. thank you