# Merging Lists in ArcMap/Python Script

Tags: python, arcmap

I am trying to plug in many .txt files into ArcMap using the below code:

```
myList=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
print myList



with open('C://folder//myList.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for fname in windList:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write(line)
```

All this does is take multiple text files and essentially merge the two together.

This results in an error shown here:

```
with open(fname) as infile:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'C'
```

Any ideas?

Thanks for any help you can offer

Comment: Does the `C://folder` folder exist?

Comment: Seems that your text file contains some unicode characters. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1207479/2089675) might be of some help

Comment: @Aaron I altered the path so it was easier to read. I have the correct path in my actual code though, I triple checked that.

Comment: Well which file is it trying to open? Print `fname` before opening. But I suspect your mistake is that `windList` is a string. What is `windList`?

Comment: @stefanPochmann   In ArcMap, I added a script which had a parameter that takes multiple text files. I thought this would create it as a list.

Comment: @Will B It won't create it as a list, it creates it as a string, with each input separated by a semicolon. You will have to do call the split function to create the list.