# How to add columns of 2 RDDs to from a single RDD and then do aggregation of rows based on date data in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, aggregate, pyspark, rdd

I have two `RDDs` in PySpark:

**RDD1:**

```
[(u'2013-01-31 00:00:00', u'a', u'Pab', u'abc', u'd'),(u'2013-01-31 00:00:00', u'a', u'ab', u'abc', u'g'),.....]
```

**RDD2:**

```
[(u'41',u'42.0'),(u'24',u'98.0'),....]
```

Both `RDDs` have same number or rows. Now what I want to do is take all the columns in each row from RDD1(converted from `unicode` to normal `string`) and the 2nd column from each row in RDD2 (converted from `unicode string` to `float` ) and form a new RDD with that. So the new RDD will look like this:

**RDD3:**

```
[('2013-01-31 00:00:00', 'a', 'Pab', 'abc', 'd',42.0),('2013-01-31 00:00:00', 'a', 'ab', u'abc', 'g',98.0),.....]
```

Once that is done then I want to do `aggregation` of last value in each row(the float value) in this new `RDD3` by the `date` value in 1st column. That mans all the rows where `date` is `2013-01-31 00:00:00`, their last numeric values should be added.

How can I do this in PySpark?

Comment: You don't have a key to join them, thus I think you would have to zip...

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto can you show how I can I do that?

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto will `rdd3 = izip(rdd1.toLocalIterator(),rdd2.toLocalIterator())` be sufficient?

Comment: No, that would be a local zip. You need to zip the RDDs. Check the documentation. (I use Scala, so I don't know the Python syntax either.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to [zipWithIndex](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=rdd#pyspark.RDD.zipWithIndex) your `RDDs`, this method creates a tuple with your data and with another value that represents the index of that entry, therefore you can join both `RDDs` by `index`.

Your approach should be similar to (I bet there are more efficient ways):

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([u"A", u"B", u"C", u"A", u"Z"])
rdd2 = sc.parallelize(xrange(5))

zdd1 = rdd1.zipWithIndex().map(lambda (v, k): (k, v))
zdd2 = rdd2.zipWithIndex().map(lambda (v, k): (k, v))

print zdd1.join(zdd2).collect()
```

The output will be:
`[(0, (u'A', 0)), (4, (u'Z', 4)), (1, (u'B', 1)), (2, (u'C', 2)), (3, (u'A', 3))]`, after this only a `map` is required to recompose the data. E.g. below:

```
combinedRDD = zdd1.join(zdd2).map(lambda (k, v): v)
print combinedRDD.collect()

# You can use the .zip method combinedRDD = rdd1.zip(rdd2)
```

The output will be:
`[(u'A', 0), (u'Z', 4), (u'B', 1), (u'C', 2), (u'A', 3)]`

About the data type conversion, I have had that problem before and to solve this I use [this snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207457/convert-a-unicode-string-to-a-string-in-python-containing-extra-symbols).

```
import unicodedata

convert = lambda (v1, v2): (unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', v1)
                                       .encode('ascii','ignore'), v2)

combinedRDD = combinedRDD.map(convert)
print combinedRDD.collect()
```

Will output: `[('A', 0), ('Z', 4), ('B', 1), ('C', 2), ('A', 3)]`

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question, that is combining the two rdds into one where each row is a tuple of 7, you can do this:

```
rdd3 = rdd1.zip(rdd2).map(lambda ((a,b,c,d,e), (f,g)): (a,b,c,d,e,f,g))
```

I'm not sure what you eventually need, is it just the date and the sum of the second value? If so, you don't need all the values:

```
rdd3 = rdd1.zip(rdd2).map(lambda ((a,b,c,d,e), (f,g)): (a,g))
rdd4 = rdd3.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x+y)
```

Comment: yes in rdd4 (the one after aggregation) I need the date and last value after the aggregation

Comment: so, is this answer working for you, or you need more help with this?