# i got a wrong data type from mysql by python

Tags: python, mysql

I wrote a get data from mysql by phthon like this

```
 query = ("select distinct packet  from http_sum where downloadspot = 'dilian'")
    cursor.execute(query)
    for (packet) in cursor:
       cdndata_name.append(packet)
```

As you see,it is so easy.but i got data like this : (u'panzarcn.rar',)
how to convert it to string ,thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13073070

Comment: I think you get a tuple back from your cursor. If you need only the first element then use `cdndata_name.append(packet[0])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a wrong data type, it is `unicode` and it is the data type you should be using to deal with text in your code. If you realy need to convert it to `str` look at the answers in [the question linked by @Lafexlos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13073070).