# Python split first sentence in news article and get the actual sentence using re

Tags: python, regex

For most news articles, the first sentences always start with a location follows by hyphen or a comma, such as

> KUALA LUMPUR: North Korea and Malaysia on Monday locked horns over the
>   investigation into the killing of leader Kim Jong-Un’s brother, as
>   footage emerged of the moment he was fatally attacked in a Kuala
>   Lumpur airport.
>
> PORTLAND, Maine — FairPoint Communications has asked regulators for
>   permission to stop signing up new customers for regulated landline
>   service in Scarborough, Gorham, Waterville, Kennebunk and Cape
>   Elizabeth.

I am trying to use re to separate out the later half which is the main sentence, such as

> North Korea and Malaysia on Monday locked horns over the
>   investigation into the killing of leader Kim Jong-Un’s brother, as
>   footage emerged of the moment he was fatally attacked in a Kuala
>   Lumpur airport.

I use the following regrex to separate them:

```
sep = re.split('-|:|--', sent)
```

But this doesn't work for everything, the result of second sentence is:

> ['PORTLAND, Maine \xe2\x80\x94 FairPoint Communications has asked
>   regulators for permission to stop signing up new customers for
>   regulated landline service in Scarborough, Gorham, Waterville,
>   Kennebunk and Cape Elizabeth.']

Is there anything to do with unicode? Or do I need to pass in different format of hyphen in the re code?

Is there a universal way to do this better?

Thanks.

Comment: The separator character is `'—'`, why do you split on `'--'`?

Comment: If possible, you should start using Python 3..6

Comment: @DYZ Sorry I didn't put it quite clear, because in some sentences,they use '--'

Answer (score 2):

As you've guessed, the problem is the unicode characters present in the string, because there isn't an ASCII character with the same value as an em dash the separator in `PORTLAND, Maine — FairPoint Communications` isn't interpreted nicely and becomes `\xe2\x80\x94` rather than `\u2014`.

There are a few options that will allow you to do what you want to:

- define the source code encoding as unicode (set `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` as either of the first two lines) and add the extra character to your regex.
- you can convert the string to ACSII using one of the available libraries (see [convert a unicode string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207457/convert-a-unicode-string-to-a-string-in-python-containing-extra-symbols))
- use a unicode compatible regex with re (`sep = re.split(ur'-|:|--|\u2014', sent)`)
- or as advised in the re [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.U) use the [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) module.

Comment: ```pattern = '[:{}]'.format(chr(8212))``` - would also work (Python 3.6).

Answer (score 0):

Since, your second sentence contains [UNICODE](http://unicode.org/charts/) character, you need to [define source code encoding](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) before executing your code as python's default encoding is [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/). Moreover, you're trying to spit the sentence using wrong character `--`. It needs to be `—` *(it's a UNICODE)*

**python** ( **[demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMclI4eXFUQWdyaUE)** )

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
sent = "PORTLAND, Maine — FairPoint Communications has asked regulators for permission to stop signing up new customers for regulated landline service in Scarborough, Gorham, Waterville, Kennebunk and Cape Elizabeth."
sep = re.split('-|:|—', sent)
print sep
```

Comment: OP wants to split on ```chr(8212)``` *or* ```':'```