# Unicode as String without conversion Python

Tags: python, unicode

I'm trying to convert unicode text to string literally, but I don't seem to find a way to do this.

```
input= u'/123/123/123'
```

convert to string:

```
output="/123/123/123"
```

If I try to do str(), it will encode it and if I try to loop over the text and convert letter by letter, it will give me each one of the unicode characters.

EDIT: Take into consideration that the objective is not to convert the string but to take the letters in the unicode text and create a string. If I follow the link provided in the comment:

[Convert a Unicode string to a string in Python (containing extra symbols)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207457/convert-a-unicode-string-to-a-string-in-python-containing-extra-symbols)

```
import unicodedata
unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', input).encode('ascii','ignore')
```

output='SSS'

and as it is possible to see..it is not the expected output.

**Edit**: I wrote as an example the unicode u'/123' but Im trying to convert chinese characters, example:

```
a=u'\u6c34'

str(a)

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u6c34' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

output_expected="\u6c34"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a Unicode string to a string in Python (containing extra symbols)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207457/convert-a-unicode-string-to-a-string-in-python-containing-extra-symbols)

Comment: I dont think is a duplicate, as I don't want to convert any character but to literally write the same text but in a string. @CIsForCookies take into account that the question are not even similar.

Comment: So what exactly is the expected outptu for `u'\u6c34'`?

Comment: @MarkRansom output="\u6c34" and not the chinese character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do it the hard way.

```
ascii_printable = set(unichr(i) for i in range(0x20, 0x7f))

def convert(ch):
    if ch in ascii_printable:
        return ch
    ix = ord(ch)
    if ix < 0x100:
        return '\\x%02x' % ix
    elif ix < 0x10000:
        return '\\u%04x' % ix
    return '\\U%08x' % ix

output = ''.join(convert(ch) for ch in input)
```

For Python 3 use `chr` instead of `unichr`.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to convert it with str() as you mention in your question, and it does work for me. You can check the encoding with type().

```
>>> input= u'/123/123/123'
>>> type(input)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> output=str(input)
>>> print output
/123/123/123
>>> type(output)
<type 'str'>
```

How do you try to iterate among the letters? I've tried and they are still as a string. You could convert the input first and then do whatever you want once they are str:

> > > letters = [x for x in output]
> > >       for letter in letters:
> > >           ...     print type(letter)
> > >           ...

I hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for your input, please review my edit. The str() command in particular is not working well trying to convert chinese characters

Comment: Oh! I see, OK! Sorry, I've never had to deal with chinese characters! Hope you find the solution!

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do it the easy way:

```
>>> a=u'\x83\u6c34\U00103ABC'
>>> a.encode('unicode_escape')
'\\x83\\u6c34\\U00103abc'
>>> print a.encode('unicode_escape')
\x83\u6c34\U00103abc
```

Answer (score 1):

Somebody wrote a really complete code for doing this, so cool, [sources](https://blog.luminoso.com/2012/08/20/fix-unicode-mistakes-with-python/):

```
import unicodedata

def fix_bad_unicode(text):
    if not isinstance(text, unicode):
        raise TypeError("This isn't even decoded into Unicode yet. "
                        "Decode it first.")
    if len(text) == 0:
        return text

    maxord = max(ord(char) for char in text)
    tried_fixing = []
    if maxord < 128:
        # Hooray! It's ASCII!
        return text
    else:
        attempts = [(text, text_badness(text) + len(text))]
        if maxord < 256:
            tried_fixing = reinterpret_latin1_as_utf8(text)
            tried_fixing2 = reinterpret_latin1_as_windows1252(text)
            attempts.append((tried_fixing, text_cost(tried_fixing)))
            attempts.append((tried_fixing2, text_cost(tried_fixing2)))
        elif all(ord(char) in WINDOWS_1252_CODEPOINTS for char in text):
            tried_fixing = reinterpret_windows1252_as_utf8(text)
            attempts.append((tried_fixing, text_cost(tried_fixing)))
        else:
            # We can't imagine how this would be anything but valid text.
            return text

        # Sort the results by badness
        attempts.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
        #print attempts
        goodtext = attempts[0][0]
        if goodtext == text:
            return goodtext
        else:
            return fix_bad_unicode(goodtext)

def reinterpret_latin1_as_utf8(wrongtext):
    newbytes = wrongtext.encode('latin-1', 'replace')
    return newbytes.decode('utf-8', 'replace')

def reinterpret_windows1252_as_utf8(wrongtext):
    altered_bytes = []
    for char in wrongtext:
        if ord(char) in WINDOWS_1252_GREMLINS:
            altered_bytes.append(char.encode('WINDOWS_1252'))
        else:
            altered_bytes.append(char.encode('latin-1', 'replace'))
    return ''.join(altered_bytes).decode('utf-8', 'replace')

def reinterpret_latin1_as_windows1252(wrongtext):
    return wrongtext.encode('latin-1').decode('WINDOWS_1252', 'replace')

def text_badness(text):
    assert isinstance(text, unicode)
    errors = 0
    very_weird_things = 0
    weird_things = 0
    prev_letter_script = None
    for pos in xrange(len(text)):
        char = text[pos]
        index = ord(char)
        if index < 256:
            weird_things += SINGLE_BYTE_WEIRDNESS[index]
            if SINGLE_BYTE_LETTERS[index]:
                prev_letter_script = 'latin'
            else:
                prev_letter_script = None
        else:
            category = unicodedata.category(char)
            if category == 'Co':
                # Unassigned or private use
                errors += 1
            elif index == 0xfffd:
                # Replacement character
                errors += 1
            elif index in WINDOWS_1252_GREMLINS:
                lowchar = char.encode('WINDOWS_1252').decode('latin-1')
                weird_things += SINGLE_BYTE_WEIRDNESS[ord(lowchar)] - 0.5

            if category.startswith('L'):
                name = unicodedata.name(char)
                scriptname = name.split()[0]
                freq, script = SCRIPT_TABLE.get(scriptname, (0, 'other'))
                if prev_letter_script:
                    if script != prev_letter_script:
                        very_weird_things += 1
                    if freq == 1:
                        weird_things += 2
                    elif freq == 0:
                        very_weird_things += 1
                prev_letter_script = script
            else:
                prev_letter_script = None

    return 100 * errors + 10 * very_weird_things + weird_things

def text_cost(text):
    """
    Assign a cost function to the length plus weirdness of a text string.
    """
    return text_badness(text) + len(text)
WINDOWS_1252_GREMLINS = [
    # adapted from http://effbot.org/zone/unicode-gremlins.htm
    0x0152,  # LATIN CAPITAL LIGATURE OE
    0x0153,  # LATIN SMALL LIGATURE OE
    0x0160,  # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S WITH CARON
    0x0161,  # LATIN SMALL LETTER S WITH CARON
    0x0178,  # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS
    0x017E,  # LATIN SMALL LETTER Z WITH CARON
    0x017D,  # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z WITH CARON
    0x0192,  # LATIN SMALL LETTER F WITH HOOK
    0x02C6,  # MODIFIER LETTER CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT
    0x02DC,  # SMALL TILDE
    0x2013,  # EN DASH
    0x2014,  # EM DASH
    0x201A,  # SINGLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK
    0x201C,  # LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
    0x201D,  # RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
    0x201E,  # DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK
    0x2018,  # LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
    0x2019,  # RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
    0x2020,  # DAGGER
    0x2021,  # DOUBLE DAGGER
    0x2022,  # BULLET
    0x2026,  # HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
    0x2030,  # PER MILLE SIGN
    0x2039,  # SINGLE LEFT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK
    0x203A,  # SINGLE RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK
    0x20AC,  # EURO SIGN
    0x2122,  # TRADE MARK SIGN
]

# a list of Unicode characters that might appear in Windows-1252 text
WINDOWS_1252_CODEPOINTS = range(256) + WINDOWS_1252_GREMLINS

# Rank the characters typically represented by a single byte -- that is, in
# Latin-1 or Windows-1252 -- by how weird it would be to see them in running
# text.
#
#   0 = not weird at all
#   1 = rare punctuation or rare letter that someone could certainly
#       have a good reason to use. All Windows-1252 gremlins are at least
#       weirdness 1.
#   2 = things that probably don't appear next to letters or other
#       symbols, such as math or currency symbols
#   3 = obscure symbols that nobody would go out of their way to use
#       (includes symbols that were replaced in ISO-8859-15)
#   4 = why would you use this?
#   5 = unprintable control character
#
# The Portuguese letter Ã (0xc3) is marked as weird because it would usually
# appear in the middle of a word in actual Portuguese, and meanwhile it
# appears in the mis-encodings of many common characters.

SINGLE_BYTE_WEIRDNESS = (
#   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,  # 0x00
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,  # 0x10
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  # 0x20
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  # 0x30
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  # 0x40
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  # 0x50
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  # 0x60
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5,  # 0x70
    2, 5, 1, 4, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 5,  # 0x80
    5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1,  # 0x90
    1, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 0, 3, 1, 1, 4,  # 0xa0
    2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0,  # 0xb0
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  # 0xc0
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  # 0xd0
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  # 0xe0
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  # 0xf0
)

# Pre-cache the Unicode data saying which of these first 256 characters are
# letters. We'll need it often.
SINGLE_BYTE_LETTERS = [
    unicodedata.category(unichr(i)).startswith('L')
    for i in xrange(256)
]

# A table telling us how to interpret the first word of a letter's Unicode
# name. The number indicates how frequently we expect this script to be used
# on computers. Many scripts not included here are assumed to have a frequency
# of "0" -- if you're going to write in Linear B using Unicode, you're
# probably aware enough of encoding issues to get it right.
#
# The lowercase name is a general category -- for example, Han characters and
# Hiragana characters are very frequently adjacent in Japanese, so they all go
# into category 'cjk'. Letters of different categories are assumed not to
# appear next to each other often.
SCRIPT_TABLE = {
    'LATIN': (3, 'latin'),
    'CJK': (2, 'cjk'),
    'ARABIC': (2, 'arabic'),
    'CYRILLIC': (2, 'cyrillic'),
    'GREEK': (2, 'greek'),
    'HEBREW': (2, 'hebrew'),
    'KATAKANA': (2, 'cjk'),
    'HIRAGANA': (2, 'cjk'),
    'HIRAGANA-KATAKANA': (2, 'cjk'),
    'HANGUL': (2, 'cjk'),
    'DEVANAGARI': (2, 'devanagari'),
    'THAI': (2, 'thai'),
    'FULLWIDTH': (2, 'cjk'),
    'MODIFIER': (2, None),
    'HALFWIDTH': (1, 'cjk'),
    'BENGALI': (1, 'bengali'),
    'LAO': (1, 'lao'),
    'KHMER': (1, 'khmer'),
    'TELUGU': (1, 'telugu'),
    'MALAYALAM': (1, 'malayalam'),
    'SINHALA': (1, 'sinhala'),
    'TAMIL': (1, 'tamil'),
    'GEORGIAN': (1, 'georgian'),
    'ARMENIAN': (1, 'armenian'),
    'KANNADA': (1, 'kannada'),  # mostly used for looks of disapproval
    'MASCULINE': (1, 'latin'),
    'FEMININE': (1, 'latin')
}
```

> Then you just call the method:

```
fix_bad_unicode(u'aあä')

>> u'a\u3042\xe4'
```

Comment: Take into consideration that im expecting my output to have the same letters, input=u'/123' and output="/123". If I try your answer, I obtain " " and that is not my expected output

Comment: @chuseuiti sorry, I did not understand the question, now I have updated it, let me know if that's what you needed

Comment: @chuseuiti don't forget to accept the answer with the (✓) if was useful :)

Comment: I didnt accept it at the end, because I retested it with chinese characters and it didnt work. Please review my edit and thanks!

Comment: @chuseuiti I updated right now, let me know if that's waht you want

Comment: @chuseuiti I think I found what you're looking at, take a look at this [post](https://blog.luminoso.com/2012/08/20/fix-unicode-mistakes-with-python/)