# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec, how to solve?

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, decode

I'm trying to make sure there is any string issue in one column called `Comment` from my dataframe `headlamp`

The reason is because I'm trying to export the dataframe later to excel by using `.to_excel()` and the unicode error is always raised.

I have read a lot of materials online and also here to solve this issue, however, I couldn't manage it so far.
I tried to solve by using the `encode()` like the code below, however, I still having the same issue.

```
headlamp = part_dataframe(ro, 'PN 3D', '921')
headlamp['Comment'] = headlamp.Comment.apply(lambda x: x.encode('ascii', 
'ignore'))
headlamp['word'] = headlamp.Comment.str.split().apply(lambda x: 
pd.value_counts(x).to_dict())
len(headlamp)
```

Error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-29454fde650e> in <module>()
  1 headlamp = part_dataframe(ro, 'PN 3D', '921')
----> 2 headlamp['Comment'] = headlamp.Comment.apply(lambda x: 
x.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
  3 headlamp['word'] = headlamp.Comment.str.split().apply(lambda x: 
  4 pd.value_counts(x).to_dict())
  5 len(headlamp)

C:\Users\Rafael\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-
packages\pandas\core\series.pyc in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, 
**kwds)
2218         else:
2219             values = self.asobject
-> 2220             mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
2221 
2222         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas\src\inference.pyx in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas\lib.c:62658)()

<ipython-input-57-29454fde650e> in <lambda>(x)
  1 headlamp = part_dataframe(ro, 'PN 3D', '921')
----> 2 headlamp['Comment'] = headlamp.Comment.apply(lambda x: 
x.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
  3 headlamp['word'] = headlamp.Comment.str.split().apply(lambda x: 
  4 pd.value_counts(x).to_dict())
  5 len(headlamp)

 UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb4 in position 71: 
 ordinal not in range(128)
```

I'm complete lost on this matter, therefore, any help will be highly appreciated.

I'm using Jupyter Ipython

Comment: Is this Python 2? Also, please show the full traceback, so we can see at which line the exception is raised.

Comment: Note that the exception is related to *de*coding, so the `encode` method itself isn't raising it. However, if this is Python 2, an implicit decoding step might be involved (automatic coercion from `str` to `unicode`).

Comment: I had update the question with the full traceback, regarding your 2 comment, could explain me better please? My python is 2.7

Comment: I'm not familiar with pandas' data model, but you could try `x.decode('latin-1').encode('ascii', 'ignore')` in the lambda expression. If you don't know the difference between the `str` and `unicode` types, you need to read up on the topic or switch to Python 3 (where you bump into this kind of problem much less frequently).

Answer (score 0):

`0xb4` is the unicode character for the backtick: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00b4/index.htm

It looks like there's a non-ascii character in the input you have. Try encoding it to `utf-8` instead and see if that helps.

If you still need it in ascii, you could try this solution: [Convert a Unicode string to a string in Python (containing extra symbols)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207457/convert-a-unicode-string-to-a-string-in-python-containing-extra-symbols)

Comment: Thank you for help, it is not necessary to be in ascii, I was just trying different types un order to see which one would solve. I tried both of your suggestiona and still didnt work, do you have any other suggestion? Thank you in advance

Comment: Try using the library from other stack overflow link I sent and see if that gives an error!

Comment: I have tried some of the sugestions on that link and I couldnt make it work. To be honest I dont even if I'm doing it right. Can you help me?, How do you would write my code that I wrote in my question in order to solve it according to your suggestion

Comment: `U+00B4` is the acute accent, not the backtick (which is `U+0060` and is contained in ASCII).