# Converting a split string representation of a list into a string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, list

i have read up on remove the character 'u' in a list but it does not work in my case :

```
[u"[u'DUTY,", u'RHODE', u'ISLAND', u'STATE', u'ASSOCIATION', u'OF', u'FIRE', u"OF']"]

**Expected Output** : DUTY RHODE ISLAND STATE ASSOCIATION OF FIRE OF
```

If i use :

```
list = [u"[u'DUTY,", u'RHODE', u'ISLAND', u'STATE', u'ASSOCIATION', u'OF', u'FIRE', u"OF']"]

new_list = "%s, %s" % (list[-1], ' '.join(list[:-1]))

Output will : u"OF'], [u'DUTY, RHODE ISLAND STATE ASSOCIATION OF FIRE FIGHTERS LINE"
```

If

```
next_list = [str(' '.join(filter(None, new_list)))]
Output is: ["[u'DUTY, RHODE ISLAND STATE ASSOCIATION OF FIRE FIGHTERS LINE OF']"]
```

If :

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval(' '.join(list))[0]

Output is : u'DUTY, RHODE ISLAND STATE ASSOCIATION OF FIRE FIGHTERS LINE OF'
```

Thanks

Comment: i guess this answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207457/convert-a-unicode-string-to-a-string-in-python-containing-extra-symbols

Comment: @KamiloVasquezCaro there are extra u as a prefix in list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this quickly using [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast

s = ["[u'DUTY,", 'RHODE', 'ISLAND', 'STATE', 'ASSOCIATION', 'OF', 'FIRE', "OF']"]
out = ast.literal_eval(' '.join(s))[0]

print(str(out)) # the str bit is redundant for python3
'DUTY, RHODE ISLAND STATE ASSOCIATION OF FIRE OF'
```

Comment: using your methods output is:  u'DUTY, RHODE ISLAND STATE ASSOCIATION OF FIRE FIGHTERS LINE OF'

Comment: there are extra u in list

Comment: @SNTiwari Run `out = str(out); print(out)`