# Unicode within Maya

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, unicode, maya

In my script (written in Sublime Test) I've a comment that reads:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import unicodedata

# Bööm! Bööm! Shake shake the room!
print u"Bööm! Bööm! Shake shake the room!"
```

Which works fine in a command prompt window.

However, when dragging and dropping the script into Maya's script editor the same line reads:

```
# BÃ¶Ã¶m! BÃ¶Ã¶m! Shake shake the room!
print u"BÃ¶Ã¶m! BÃ¶Ã¶m! Shake shake the room!"
```

How do I make the comment read as intended?

Comment: BTW having `#!/usr/bin/python` for a maya script is a bit misleading, because your definitely not calling `usr/bin/python` on any system when using maya unless you actually spent a ton of time configuring your system python to be maya python.

Comment: @joojaa He he he. Force of habit. I'll remove it. Shebang begone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely Windows' problem. In macOS El Capital and macOS Sierra it works fine.

```
import unicodedata
print u"Bööm! Bööm! Shake shake the room!"

#result: Bööm! Bööm! Shake shake the room!
```

Although it's about different topic, look at this useful SO post: [Convert a Unicode string to a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207457/convert-a-unicode-string-to-a-string-in-python-containing-extra-symbols). This post might give you some ideas.

Maybe, you should try this method:

```
u = u"Bööm! Bööm! Shake shake the room!"
e = u.encode('utf8')
print e

#result: Bööm! Bööm! Shake shake the room!
```

Comment: It's a Maya script editor problem.  It didn't open the file using UTF-8 encoding.