# Trouble converting a pandas dataframe into a list with the right utf-8 encoding

Tags: python, pandas, encoding

I'm trying to convert a Pandas Dataframe into a list, which works but I have some issues with the encoding. I hope someone can give me advice on how to handle this problem. Right now, I'm using **Python 2.7**.

I'm loading an excel file and it loads correctly.

I'm using following code and I get following output:

```
germanStatesExcelFile='German_States.xlsx'
ePath_german_states=(os.path.dirname(__file__))+'/'+germanStatesExcelFile
german_states = pd.read_excel(ePath_german_states)
print("doc " + str(german_states))
```

Output:

```
                    states
0        baden-württemberg
1                   bayern
2                   hessen
3          rheinland-pfalz
4                 saarland
5      nordrhein-westfalen
```

The next step is converting this Dataframe into a list, which I do with following code:

```
german_states = german_states['states'].tolist()
```

Output:

```
[u'baden-w\xfcrttemberg', u'bayern', u'hessen', u'rheinland-pfalz', u'saarland', u'nordrhein-westfalen']
```

It seems like the list is converting utf-8 not right. so i tried following step:

```
german_states = [x.encode('utf-8') for x in german_states]
```

Output:

```
['baden-w\xc3\xbcrttemberg', 'bayern', 'hessen', 'rheinland-pfalz', 'saarland', 'nordrhein-westfalen']
```

I would like to have following Output:

```
['baden-württemberg', 'bayern', 'hessen', 'rheinland-pfalz', 'saarland', 'nordrhein-westfalen']
```

Comment: Try decoding ie `german_states['states'].str.decode('utf-8').tolist()`

Comment: i get following error msg: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: use it after ur read excel not after converting it to list.. And to be on safer side use `...astype('str').str.decode(...`  if you have missing values as nan

Answer (score 1):

Little late to the party, but if encoding to utf-8 like below doesn't work, you could use the [unicodedata.normalize](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) module

```
german_states_decoded = [x.encode('utf-8') for x in german_states]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your strings only contain ascii characters, you could try python's in-built `str`, as below. This works with the strings you provided, but may not necessarily be the case.

Otherwise, there are a number of good answers to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207457/convert-a-unicode-string-to-a-string-in-python-containing-extra-symbols).

```
german_states = [u'baden-w\xfcrttemberg', u'bayern', u'hessen', u'rheinland-pfalz', u'saarland', u'nordrhein-westfalen']

german_states = list(map(str, german_states))

# ['baden-württemberg', 'bayern', 'hessen', 'rheinland-pfalz', 'saarland', 'nordrhein-westfalen']
```

Comment: I tried your code, but i still get this output:  


    ['baden-w\xc3\xbcrttemberg', 'bayern', 'hessen', 'rheinland-pfalz', 'saarland', 'nordrhein-westfalen']

Comment: must be an environment issue (e.g. Windows dependent). I suggest you look at the answer on the link I provided. It's a bit more complex, but should work.