# Convert the values in tuples from unicode to string, when the tuples are in a list of a list in Python 2.7

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, unicode, ascii

How can I convert the values in tuples from unicode to string, when the tuples are in a list of a list in Python 2.7

Here is an example for the same -

From

```
 unicode_list=[[(u'Mr.', u'UNK'), (u'Vinken', u'UNK'), (u'is', u'UNK'), (u'chairman', u'UNK'), (u'of', u'UNK'), (u'Elsevier', u'UNK'), (u'N.V.', u'UNK'), (u',', u'UNK'), (u'the', u'UNK'), (u'Dutch', u'UNK'), (u'publishing', u'UNK'), (u'group', u'UNK'), (u'.', u'UNK')], [(u'Rudolph', u'UNK'), (u'Agnew', u'UNK'), (u',', u'UNK'), (u'55', u'UNK'), (u'years', u'UNK'), (u'old', u'UNK'), (u'and', u'UNK'), (u'former', u'UNK'), (u'chairman', u'UNK'), (u'of', u'UNK'), (u'Consolidated', u'UNK'), (u'Gold', u'UNK'), (u'Fields', u'UNK'), (u'PLC', u'UNK'), (u',', u'UNK'), (u'was', u'UNK'), (u'named', u'UNK'), (u'*-1', u'UNK'), (u'a', u'UNK'), (u'nonexecutive', u'UNK'), (u'director', u'UNK'), (u'of', u'UNK'), (u'this', u'UNK'), (u'British', u'UNK'), (u'industrial', u'UNK'), (u'conglomerate', u'UNK'), (u'.', u'UNK')], [(u'A', u'UNK'), (u'form', u'UNK'), (u'of', u'UNK'), (u'asbestos', u'UNK'), (u'once', u'UNK'), (u'used', u'UNK'), (u'*', u'UNK'), (u'*', u'UNK'), (u'to', u'UNK'), (u'make', u'UNK'), (u'Kent', u'UNK'), (u'cigarette', u'UNK'), (u'filters', u'UNK'), (u'has', u'UNK'), (u'caused', u'UNK'), (u'a', u'UNK'), (u'high', u'UNK'), (u'percentage', u'UNK'), (u'of', u'UNK'), (u'cancer', u'UNK'), (u'deaths', u'UNK'), (u'among', u'UNK'), (u'a', u'UNK'), (u'group', u'UNK'), (u'of', u'UNK'), (u'workers', u'UNK'), (u'exposed', u'UNK'), (u'*', u'UNK'), (u'to', u'UNK'), (u'it', u'UNK'), (u'more', u'UNK'), (u'than', u'UNK'), (u'30', u'UNK'), (u'years', u'UNK'), (u'ago', u'UNK'), (u',', u'UNK'), (u'researchers', u'UNK'), (u'reported', u'UNK'), (u'0', u'UNK'), (u'*T*-1', u'UNK'), (u'.', u'UNK')], [(u'The', u'UNK'), (u'asbestos', u'UNK'), (u'fiber', u'UNK'), (u',', u'UNK'), (u'crocidolite', u'UNK'), (u',', u'UNK'), (u'is', u'UNK'), (u'unusually', u'UNK'), (u'resilient', u'UNK'), (u'once', u'UNK'), (u'it', u'UNK'), (u'enters', u'UNK'), (u'the', u'UNK'), (u'lungs', u'UNK'), (u',', u'UNK'), (u'with', u'UNK'), (u'even', u'UNK'), (u'brief', u'UNK'), (u'exposures', u'UNK'), (u'to', u'UNK'), (u'it', u'UNK'), (u'causing', u'UNK'), (u'symptoms', u'UNK'), (u'that', u'UNK'), (u'*T*-1', u'UNK'), (u'show', u'UNK'), (u'up', u'UNK'), (u'decades', u'UNK'), (u'later', u'UNK'), (u',', u'UNK'), (u'researchers', u'UNK'), (u'said', u'UNK'), (u'0', u'UNK'), (u'*T*-2', u'UNK'), (u'.', u'UNK')]]
```

to

```
 ascii_list=[[('Mr.', 'NOUN'), ('Vinken', 'NOUN'), ('is', 'VERB'), ('chairman', 'NOUN'), ('of', 'ADP'), ('Elsevier', 'NOUN'), ('N.V.', 'NOUN'), (',', '.'), ('the', 'DET'), ('Dutch', 'NOUN'), ('publishing', 'VERB'), ('group', 'NOUN'), ('.', '.')], [('Rudolph', 'NOUN'), ('Agnew', 'NOUN'), (',', '.'), ('55', 'NUM'), ('years', 'NOUN'), ('old', 'ADJ'), ('and', 'CONJ'), ('former', 'ADJ'), ('chairman', 'NOUN'), ('of', 'ADP'), ('Consolidated', 'NOUN'), ('Gold', 'NOUN'), ('Fields', 'NOUN'), ('PLC', 'NOUN'), (',', '.'), ('was', 'VERB'), ('named', 'VERB'), ('*-1', 'X'), ('a', 'DET'), ('nonexecutive', 'ADJ'), ('director', 'NOUN'), ('of', 'ADP'), ('this', 'DET'), ('British', 'ADJ'), ('industrial', 'ADJ'), ('conglomerate', 'NOUN'), ('.', '.')], [('A', 'DET'), ('form', 'NOUN'), ('of', 'ADP'), ('asbestos', 'NOUN'), ('once', 'ADV'), ('used', 'VERB'), ('*', 'X'), ('*', 'X'), ('to', 'PRT'), ('make', 'VERB'), ('Kent', 'NOUN'), ('cigarette', 'NOUN'), ('filters', 'NOUN'), ('has', 'VERB'), ('caused', 'VERB'), ('a', 'DET'), ('high', 'ADJ'), ('percentage', 'NOUN'), ('of', 'ADP'), ('cancer', 'NOUN'), ('deaths', 'NOUN'), ('among', 'ADP'), ('a', 'DET'), ('group', 'NOUN'), ('of', 'ADP'), ('workers', 'NOUN'), ('exposed', 'VERB'), ('*', 'X'), ('to', 'PRT'), ('it', 'PRON'), ('more', 'ADV'), ('than', 'ADP'), ('30', 'NUM'), ('years', 'NOUN'), ('ago', 'ADP'), (',', '.'), ('researchers', 'NOUN'), ('reported', 'VERB'), ('0', 'X'), ('*T*-1', 'X'), ('.', '.')], [('The', 'DET'), ('asbestos', 'NOUN'), ('fiber', 'NOUN'), (',', '.'), ('crocidolite', 'NOUN'), (',', '.'), ('is', 'VERB'), ('unusually', 'ADV'), ('resilient', 'ADJ'), ('once', 'ADP'), ('it', 'PRON'), ('enters', 'VERB'), ('the', 'DET'), ('lungs', 'NOUN'), (',', '.'), ('with', 'ADP'), ('even', 'ADV'), ('brief', 'ADJ'), ('exposures', 'NOUN'), ('to', 'PRT'), ('it', 'PRON'), ('causing', 'VERB'), ('symptoms', 'NOUN'), ('that', 'DET'), ('*T*-1', 'X'), ('show', 'VERB'), ('up', 'PRT'), ('decades', 'NOUN'), ('later', 'ADJ'), (',', '.'), ('researchers', 'NOUN'), ('said', 'VERB'), ('0', 'X'), ('*T*-2', 'X'), ('.', '.')]]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207457/convert-a-unicode-string-to-a-string-in-python-containing-extra-symbols

Comment: @ForceBru [stackoverflow.com/questions/1207457/…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207457/convert-a-unicode-string-to-a-string-in-python-containing-extra-symbols) talks about converting  a Unicode string to string. But here it is a case of a nested list.

Comment: But this case can be reduced to converting Unicode to string. Simply walk the data structure and convert each element to string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the conversion with a nested list comprehension:

```
>>> ascii_list  = [[tuple([str(x) for x in tpl]) 
...  for tpl in sublist]
...  for sublist in unicode_list]
```

This creates a new list of lists - the original tuples can't be converted as they are, effectively, immutable.

Comment: I don't really understand why you'd bother doing this though - in Python 2 unicode and str are pretty much interchangeable if you're only handling ASCII.

Comment: still one bug remaining. it is converting all the 2nd values to 'UNK'. e.g.,

 `ascii_list  =[[('Mr.', 'UNK'), ('Vinken', 'UNK'), ('is', 'UNK'), ('chairman', 'UNK'), ('of', 'UNK'), ('Elsevier', 'UNK'), ('N.V.', 'UNK'), (',', 'UNK'), ('the', 'UNK'), ('Dutch', 'UNK'), ('publishing', 'UNK'), ('group', 'UNK'), ('.', 'UNK')]]`

Comment: No, you were still using the original `unicode_list` from your question.  It works on the new input that you edited in afterwards too (although clearly it can't conver rUNK to NOUN or VERB without additional logic.  Please don't change question requirements _after_ the question has been answered - ask a new question instead.