# Change list according to dictionary items

Tags: python, dictionary

Hello I have a list that looks like:

```
>>>ids
 '70723295',
 '75198124',
 '140',
 '199200',
 '583561',
 '71496270',
 '69838760',
 '70545907',
 ...]
```

I also have a dictionary that gives those numbers a 'name'. Now I want to create a new list that contains only the names, in the order like the numbers before.. so replace the numbers in the right order with the right names from the dictionary.

I tried:

```
with open('/home/anja/Schreibtisch/Master/ABA/alltogether/filelist.txt') as f:
    ids = [line.strip() for line in f.read().split('\n')]

rev_subs = { v:k for v,k in dictionary.items()}
new_list=[rev_subs.get(item,item)  for item in ids]

#dict looks like:
 '16411': 'Itgax',
 '241041': 'Gm4956',
 '22419': 'Wnt5b',
 '20174': 'Ruvbl2',
 '71833': 'Dcaf7',
 ...}
```

But new_list is still the same as ids.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are the keys of `dictionary` integers or strings?

Comment: @blhsing  bs4.element.NavigableString,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the dictionary keys are not in the format you think? Maybe the dictionary contains integers, meanwhile the ids are strings. I would investigate on that, it seems a mismatch of types more than an empty (or non-matching) dictionary.

Comment: if I do types1 = set(type(k) for k in final_dictionary1.keys())I got:  {NoneType, bs4.element.NavigableString}

Comment: You don't have a string, but rather _bs4.element.NavigableString_, so the matching doesn't work. 

You need to convert you _bs4.element.NavigableString_ objects to string, looking at the documentation at https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/, you need to do unicode(your_element) to convert it.

Comment: But then I have no dictionary anymore..  how can I use that then for my new list? Looks like that now: \n66583\n100504140\n20747\n105638\n320237\n382030\n56758'

Comment: I have no experience with BeautifulSoup (I just know because I searched for your class), I don't really know how to handle that (I'd look for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207457/convert-a-unicode-string-to-a-string-in-python-containing-extra-symbols)). At the core, when you create your dictionary, your key must be comparable a string. Btw, your IDs looks a lot like integers, are you sure using string is the best approach? Note, if IDs have leading 0s (e.g. 0042), then I'm wrong and you have to use a string.

Answer (score 1):

Your dictionary keys are `bs4.element.NavigableString` objects rather than strings, so you cannot use strings as keys to look up its values.

You can fix this by converting the keys to strings when you build `rev_subs`:

```
rev_subs = {str(k): v for k, v in dictionary.items()}
```