# How to convert unicode to char in nested list/dict in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

There are lots of question about this but for my issue I couldn't find a solution.

I have Json file and it has "Yeşil" in it. When I read that file with json.load() "ş" becomes "\u015f". However I need it to be "ş".

I have a list like this (trimmed):

```
[{'count': 75.95, 'another_list': [{'name': 'name1', 'val': 'val1'}, {'surname': 'surname1', 'val': 'Ye\\u015fil', 'image': 'example.jpg'}], 'anotherCount': 10}]
```

As you can see 'val' : 'Ye\u015fil' is like this. I want to turn it to "Yeşil".

You may wonder why I need this, because I am sending some post requests and It doesn't convert it to "ş". It stays like "\u015f" this.

Is there a way that I can achieve this in python 2.7 ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207457/

Comment: I have checked this question. What I need to make it in this kind of list+dict