# invalid syntax when working with french accents

Tags: python-3.x, accent-sensitive

Well, I'm trying to clean my file which have codes for french accents:

```
#353= IFCPROPERTYSINGLEVALUE('Charge d''\X2\00E9\X0\clairage sp\X2\00E9\X0\cifi\X2\00E9\X0\e par surface',$,IFCREAL(10.7639104167097),$);
```

I created this little function:

```
def CleanSpace(sp):
    sp.replace("\X2\00F4\X0\","ô")
    sp.replace("\X2\00E9\X0\","é")
    return(sp)
```

but Python 3 gave me the error:

```
    sp.replace("\X2\00F4\X0\","ô")
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I resolve this, please?
Thanks in advance

Edit: if it can help, I rather tryed this line in console but answer was strange:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a='02_RADIOTHERAPIE/ ARC -plateforme recherche- Radioth\X2\00E9\X0\rapie'
>>> a
'02_RADIOTHERAPIE/ ARC -plateforme recherche- Radioth\\X2\x00E9\\X0\rapie'
>>> a.replace('\X2\00E9\X0\\','é')
'02_RADIOTHERAPIE/ ARC -plateforme recherche- Radioth\\X2\x00E9\\X0\rapie'
```

Comment: The problem is `\"` in the end of the first argument - it's interpreting the " as part of the string, instead of closing it. Drop that `\\`. The coloring should give you the hint.

Comment: Also you do not need to do this like that tell it that the input string is in unicode escape and that you want to produce a string that is UTF-8. That way you do not need to figure out all the unicode escape sequences you let Python figure it out for you :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375684/python-how-to-convert-utf-8-code-string-back-to-string

Comment: @kabanus: Thanks, yes, coloring gave me a doubt but if I drop or double this final \, no error but function 'replace' didn't worked: my prints are containing always \X2\00E9\X0\...

Comment: @Rob: I don't understand this link, too much technical for me

Comment: I don't understand - you want to take a regular string, and convert it to the appropriate unicode character? `\X2\00F4\X0` and the symbol you wrote are the same thing, I don't understand what you're trying to do. In any case, you have to drop that final backslash, that's just plain wrong, regardless.

Comment: @pim92 Sorry I wrote that quickly, it looked a lot like a byte array describing 'unicode-escape' sequence that you could use python to decode.. it is not however so disregard my comment.

Comment: @Rob: ok, no prob ;)
@kabanus: No, I have a file with some special texts like `\X2\00F4\X0` and I would like to transform these lines with something like sp.replace but or it doesn't work, or there is the error message...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a lot of tries and searches, solution for one line was to use [raw-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#why-can-t-raw-strings-r-strings-end-with-a-backslash):

```
>>> a.replace(r'\X2\00E9\X0\ '[:-1], 'é')
"#353= IFCPROPERTYSINGLEVALUE('Charge d''éclairage spécifiée par surface',$,IFCREAL(10.7639104167097),$);"
```

For more lines, it was more difficult because bytes into my file are already written and it is not because I see a '\' that it is existing...
Solution found for me was to work on bytes with [antlr4](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4)

Answer (score 1):

the \ character escapes your quotations. This means python will keep on going until it finds another quotation mark to end your string. so, in reality, your string is `\X2\00F4\X0\",` To fix this, escape the \ with an \ or remove the final one entirely.
new code:

```
sp.replace("\X2\00F4\X0\\","ô")
```

Comment: Thanks, coloring gave me a doubt but if I drop or double this final \, no error but function is not working...

Comment: Try making it a double backslash like in my answer? Or does that not work?

Comment: 'replace' didn't worked:
my prints are containing always \X2\00E9\X0\...

Comment: `sp.replace("\\X2\\00E9\\X0\\","é")`

Comment: none the better:
myline...lalala\X2\00E9\X0\itsboring

Answer (score 0):

When you put `\“` in a python string, it adds a literal `”` to the string and doesn’t close it. In the same way you can write `\‘` to get a single quote, or `\\` to get a backslash. So if I wanted to get a Python string saying:

```
“Hi,”, said Bob \
```

I wouuld write in my code:

```
“\“Hi,\“, said Bob \\”
```

Because you wrote \” and didn’t close the string after it, it carried on to the next line and messed everything up.

**Edit:**

Also, in the console you didn’t use double backslashes everywhere, so occasionally they acted as escape characters resulting in strange things. Whenever you want a string to contain a backslash in Python, write `\\`.

Your text might contain `\X2\00F4\X0\` , but in a Python string `"\\"` means a single backslash, so if you replace every backslash in your string literals with a double backslash (**not just the last one**), it should work, so

```
a.replace('\\X2\\00E9\\X0\\','é')
```

for example.

Comment: Well, as said before, with sp.replace("\X2\00F4\X0\\","ô") no more error but text is not changed in ô...

Comment: @Pim92 Answered your question (I think).