# Reading a tag from XML and printing it

Tags: python

I have the following input XML file,i read the rel_notes tag and print it...running into the following error

Input   XML:

```
<rel_notes>
    •   Please move to this build for all further test and development activities 
    •   Please use this as base build to verify compilation and sanity before any check-in happens

</rel_notes>
```

Sample python code:

```
file = open('data.xml,'r')
from xml.etree import cElementTree as etree
tree = etree.parse(file)
print('\n'.join(elem.text for elem in tree.iter('rel_notes')))
```

OUTPUT

```
   print('\n'.join(elem.text for elem in tree.iter('rel_notes')))
 File "C:\python2.7.3\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u2022' in position 9: character maps to <undefined>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with [printing Unicode to Windows console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419/python-unicode-and-the-windows-console). Namely, [the character '•'](http://codepoints.net/U+2022) can't be represented in `cp437` used by your console.

To reproduce the problem, try:

```
print u'\u2022'
```

You could set [`PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable](http://docs.python.org/2.7/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) to instruct python to replace all unrepresentable characters with corresponding xml char references:

```
T:\> set PYTHONIOENCODING=cp437:xmlcharrefreplace
T:\> python your_script.py
```

Or encode the text to bytes before printing:

```
print u'\u2022'.encode('cp437', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
```

---

<sup>answer to your initial question</sup>

[To print text of each `<build_location/>` element](http://ideone.com/hlla5W):

```
import sys
from xml.etree import cElementTree as etree

input_file = sys.stdin # filename or file object
tree = etree.parse(input_file)
print('\n'.join(elem.text for elem in tree.iter('build_location')))
```

If input file is large; [`iterparse()` could be used](http://ideone.com/BgNp0d):

```
import sys
from xml.etree import cElementTree as etree

input_file = sys.stdin
context = iter(etree.iterparse(input_file, events=('start', 'end')))
_, root = next(context) # get root element
for event, elem in context:
    if event == 'end' and elem.tag == 'build_location':
       print(elem.text)
       root.clear() # free memory
```

Comment: running into the following error     for _, elem in etree.iterparse(file):
  File "<string>", line 107, in next
cElementTree.ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0

Comment: @user1795998: is the `file` empty? Update your question with the code that you use.

Comment: its not emtpy...am using 2.7.3,can you please suggest to get it to work using 2.7.3,am using import xml.dom.minidom as minidom

Comment: @user1795998: copy-paste any of the above examples as is and replace `sys.stdin` by a filename or a file object (such as returned by `open()` function).

Comment: @user1795998: yes. cElementTree is available since Python 2.5 at least. If you click any of the links in the answer you'll see that it works on Python 2.7

Comment: @sebastian..I copied the example as is.running into an error,I updated my question with the same

Comment: @user1795998: I've updated the answer. btw, don't replace entire question next time, just append the update at the end of your question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the entire snippet above is completely helpful. But, UnicodeEncodeError usually happens when the ASCII characters aren't handled properly.

#### Example:

```
unicode_str = html.decode(<source encoding>)

encoded_str = unicode_str.encode("utf8")
```

Its already explained clearly in this answer: [Python: Convert Unicode to ASCII without errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365411/python-convert-unicode-to-ascii-without-errors)

This should at least solve the UnicodeEncodeError.