# Python nested lists replace unicode characters in strings

Tags: python, unicode, replace

Trying to replace or strip strings in this list to insert into a database which does not allow them

```
info=[[u'\xa0Buffalo\u2019s League of legends ...', '2012-09-05'], [u' \xa0RCKIN 0 - 1 WITHACK.nq\xa0  ', u'\xa0Buffalo\u2019s League of legends ...', '2012-09-05']]
```

I used this code

```
info = [[x.replace(u'\xa0', u'') for x in l] for l in info]
info = [[y.replace('\u2019s', '') for y in o] for o in info]
```

the first line worked but the second one not, any suggestions ?

Comment: I would also try to figure out why are you getting such a weird string mixing raw bytes and unicode codepoints.

Comment: What you should do is byte the bullet and learn how to handle unicode by decoding it when you read the string and then encoding it when you are ready to send it to your database.  One place to start is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365411/python-convert-unicode-to-ascii-without-errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drop the second line and do:

```
info = [[x.encode('ascii', 'ignore')  for x in l] for l in info]
```

and see if the results are acceptable. This will attempt to convert all the unicode to ascii and drop any characters that fail to convert. You just want to be sure that if you lose an important unicode character, it's not a problem.

```
>>> info=[[u'\xa0Buffalo\u2019s League of legends ...', '2012-09-05'], [u' \xa0RCKIN 0 - 1 WITHACK.nq\xa0  ', u'\xa0Buffalo\u2019s League of legends ...', '2012-09-05']]
>>> info = [[x.encode('ascii', 'ignore')  for x in l] for l in info]
>>> info
[['Buffalos League of legends ...', '2012-09-05'], [' RCKIN 0 - 1 WITHACK.nq  ', 'Buffalos League of legends ...', '2012-09-05']]
```

---

### What's going on:

You have data in your Python program that's Unicode (and that's good.)

```
>>> u = u'\u2019'
```

Best practice, for interoperability, is to write Unicode strings out to `utf-8`. These are the bytes you should be storing in your database:

```
>>> u.encode('utf-8')
'\xe2\x80\x99'
>>> utf8 = u.encode('utf-8')
>>> print utf8
’
```

And then when you read those bytes back into your program, you should then decode them:

```
>>> utf8.decode('utf8')
u'\u2019'
>>> print utf8.decode('utf8')
’
```

If your database can't handle `utf-8` then I would consider getting a new database.

Comment: I like this better than replacing.

Answer (score 4):

Because in the second form `\u2019s` is not considered as unicode string. Just prepend `u` in the replace before that element like this

```
print [[y.replace(u'\u2019s', '') for y in o] for o in info]]
```

**Output**

```
[[u'Buffalo League of legends ...', u'2012-09-05'],
 [u' RCKIN 0 - 1 WITHACK.nq  ',
  u'Buffalo League of legends ...',
  u'2012-09-05']]
```

Infact you can chain the replace, like this

```
[[x.replace(u'\xa0', '').replace(u'\u2019s', '') for x in l] for l in info]
```