# Python Pandas DataFrame read_csv UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, unicode-normalization

I have a 129 MB CSV file with 849,275 rows and 18 columns.  I'm trying to read the CSV file into a pandas `DataFrame` using `read_csv`.

When I use `encoding='cp1252'`:

```
read_file = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', encoding='cp1252')
```

The error is quite long but ultimately says this at the bottom:

```
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 41:
 character maps to <undefined>
```

When I specify: no encoding, `encoding='utf-8'`, or `encoding='utf-8-sig'`, I get:

```
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 65:
 invalid start byte
```

**QUESTION:**

I am fine with deleting these problematic characters altogether.  Better yet would be to normalize them to ASCII characters under 127. How can I do this using **JUST PANDAS**?  I'm looking for the most panda-like way if it exists.

Not to **overkill** this question but here's a list of the types of characters in one of the columns that I'm certain is causing the problem:

```
Character   Ord
    32
!   33
"   34
#   35
$    36
%   37
&   38
'   39
(   40
)   41
*   42
+   43
,   44
-   45
.   46
/   47
0   48
1   49
2   50
3   51
4   52
5   53
6   54
7   55
8   56
9   57
:   58
;   59
<   60
=   61
>   62
?   63
@   64
A   65
B   66
C   67
D   68
E   69
F   70
G   71
H   72
I   73
J   74
K   75
L   76
M   77
N   78
O   79
P   80
Q   81
R   82
S   83
T   84
U   85
V   86
W   87
X   88
Y   89
Z   90
[   91
\   92
]   93
^   94
_   95
`   96
a   97
b   98
c   99
d   100
e   101
f   102
g   103
h   104
i   105
j   106
k   107
l   108
m   109
n   110
o   111
p   112
q   113
r   114
s   115
t   116
u   117
v   118
w   119
x   120
y   121
z   122
{   123
|   124
}   125
~   126
   129
   143
   157
    160
¡   161
¢   162
£   163
§   167
¨   168
©   169
«   171
¬   172
®   174
°   176
±   177
²   178
³   179
´   180
µ   181
·   183
¸   184
¹   185
º   186
¼   188
½   189
¾   190
×   215
ß   223
à   224
á   225
â   226
ã   227
ä   228
å   229
æ   230
ç   231
è   232
é   233
ì   236
í   237
î   238
ï   239
ð   240
ñ   241
ó   243
ô   244
ö   246
ú   250
û   251
ü   252
š   353
Ž   381
ƒ   402
–   8211
—   8212
‘   8216
’   8217
‚   8218
“   8220
”   8221
„   8222
†   8224
•   8226
…   8230
‹   8249
›   8250
€   8364
™   8482
```

Answer (score 3):

The best is to use Python 3. Alternatively, this helped me in number of cases string.encode('**ascii**', **errors='ignore'**) inside read_csv:

```
read_csv(..., converters={column_x= lambda v: v.encode('ascii',errors='ignore')})
```

This link has more examples: [Python: Convert Unicode to ASCII without errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365411/python-convert-unicode-to-ascii-without-errors)

Answer (score 1):

If you completely sure that file in `windows-1251`/`cp1251`, you could try to switch off decode errors:

```
import codecs
codecs.register_error("strict", codecs.ignore_errors)
```

It helped me to read csv files under Linux that was built under Windows.