# unicode datas of a dataframe to strings

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, python-unicode, unicode-string

I have some troubles with a dataframe obtained from reading a xls file.
Every data on such dataframe has the type 'unicode' and I can't do anything with this. I wanna change it to str values. Also, iff possible, I'd like to know the reason of this fact. I heard something about 'external data', and I know that both columns and index also present the 'u' of unicode before the names of these ones. I don't know neither almost anything about encoding and I would be really grateful if someone explains something about this in addition.

I'm using Python 2 and I tryed to solve it column by column with functions as

```
.astype(str) 
.astype(basestring)
.apply(str)
```

and

```
.str.decode('iso-8859-1').str.encode('utf-8')
```

(I read this last one here and I just wrote it in my code to try another thing). I also tried

```
unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', df_bolsa[l]).encode('ascii','ignore')
```

but this last one cannot be used with a series.
I hope someone to be able to help me to clarify this matter.
Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: How about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365411/python-convert-unicode-to-ascii-without-errors

Comment: Thank you but I don't know actually how to apply that problem to mine. Anyway I will read it tomorrow to try to understand something about the encoding... thanks again!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following code.

```
for column in df:
    df[column] = df_peru[column].str.encode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1):

To help others, this version worked for me.
I was getting an error while loading my dataframe to an oracle database: "`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xea in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)`"

I am on Python ver 2.7

```
for column in df:
    df[column]=  df[column].astype(str).str.decode('utf-8')
```