# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Help me figure out whats wrong with my python code.

thats the code

```
import nltk
import re
import pickle


raw = open('tom_sawyer_shrt.txt').read()

### this is how the basic Punkt sentence tokenizer works
#sent_tokenizer=nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
#sents = sent_tokenizer.tokenize(raw)

### train & tokenize text using text
sent_trainer = nltk.tokenize.punkt.PunktSentenceTokenizer().train(raw)
sent_tokenizer = nltk.tokenize.punkt.PunktSentenceTokenizer(sent_trainer)
# break in to sentences
sents = sent_tokenizer.tokenize(raw)
# get sentence start/stop indexes
sentspan = sent_tokenizer.span_tokenize(raw)



###  Remove \n in the middle of setences, due to fixed-width formatting
for i in range(0,len(sents)-1):
    sents[i] = re.sub('(?<!\n)\n(?!\n)',' ',raw[sentspan[i][0]:sentspan[i+1][0]])

for i in range(1,len(sents)):
    if (sents[i][0:3] == '"\n\n'):
        sents[i-1] = sents[i-1]+'"\n\n'
        sents[i] = sents[i][3:]


### Loop thru each sentence, fix to 140char
i=0
tweet=[]
while (i<len(sents)):
    if (len(sents[i]) > 140):
        ntwt = int(len(sents[i])/140) + 1
        words = sents[i].split(' ')
        nwords = len(words)
        for k in range(0,ntwt):
            tweet = tweet + [
                re.sub('\A\s|\s\Z', '', ' '.join(
                words[int(k*nwords/float(ntwt)):
                      int((k+1)*nwords/float(ntwt))]
                ))]
        i=i+1
    else:
        if (i<len(sents)-1):
            if (len(sents[i])+len(sents[i+1]) <140):
                nextra = 1
                while (len(''.join(sents[i:i+nextra+1]))<140):
                    nextra=nextra+1
                tweet = tweet+[
                    re.sub('\A\s|\s\Z', '',''.join(sents[i:i+nextra]))
                    ]        
                i = i+nextra
            else:
                tweet = tweet+[re.sub('\A\s|\s\Z', '',sents[i])]
                i=i+1
        else:
            tweet = tweet+[re.sub('\A\s|\s\Z', '',sents[i])]
            i=i+1


### A last pass to clean up leading/trailing newlines/spaces.
for i in range(0,len(tweet)):
    tweet[i] = re.sub('\A\s|\s\Z','',tweet[i])

for i in range(0,len(tweet)):
    tweet[i] = re.sub('\A"\n\n','',tweet[i])


###  Save tweets to pickle file for easy reading later
output = open('tweet_list.pkl','wb')
pickle.dump(tweet,output,-1)
output.close()


listout = open('tweet_lis.txt','w')
for i in range(0,len(tweet)):
    listout.write(tweet[i])
    listout.write('\n-----------------\n')

listout.close()
```

and thats the error message

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>           File "twain_prep.py", line 13, in 
>               sent_trainer = nltk.tokenize.punkt.PunktSentenceTokenizer().train(raw)
>           File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1227, in train
>               token_cls=self._Token).get_params()
>           File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 649, in **init**
>               self.train(train_text, verbose, finalize=True)
>           File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 713, in train
>               self._train_tokens(self._tokenize_words(text), verbose)
>           File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 729, in _train_tokens
>               tokens = list(tokens)
>           File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 542, in _tokenize_words
>               for line in plaintext.split('\n'):
>           UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 1):

`UnicodeDecodeError` happens when your string has some Unicode in it. Basically, Python string handles `ascii` values only and that's why when you are sending your text to `tokenizer` it must be containing some character which is not in `ascii` list.

**So how to fix it?**

You can convert your text to `ascii` characters and ignore the 'Unicode' ones.

```
raw = raw..encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

Also, you can read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365411/python-convert-unicode-to-ascii-without-errors) to handle `Unicode` errors.