# preprocess string in python

Tags: python, string, preprocessor

I used `urllib.parse.unquote` and `html.unescape` to preprocess my string, but unexpectedly there are '\xa0' and '\u200e' characters in my string, is there a python function to do the last two replacements for me in case there are more such characters in my string?

```
# res = res.replace("%20", "") 
res = urllib.parse.unquote(res)
# res = res.replace('&nbsp;', ' ')
res = html.unescape(res)
res = res.replace('\xa0', '')
res = res.replace('\u200e', '')
```

Comment: What is wrong with the solution you have?
`replace()` replaces all occurrences.

Comment: Maybe look through the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365411/python-convert-unicode-to-ascii-without-errors)?