# Change encoding for locally stored .html files downloaded with urllib.request.urlretrieve()

Tags: python, file, unicode, utf-8, urllib

I used the following python code to save an html file to local storage:

```
url = "some_url.html
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'save/to/path')
```

This successfully saves the file with a .html extension. When I attempt to open the file with:

```
html_doc = open('save/to/path/some_url.html', 'r')
```

I get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 36255: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I think this means I am attempting to read a utf-8 file with a ascii codec. I attempted the solution found at:

[Convert Unicode to ASCII without errors in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365411/convert-unicode-to-ascii-without-errors-in-python)

But this, as well as other solutions I have found, only seem to work for encoding the file for immediate viewing and not saved files. I cannot find one that works for altering the encoding of a locally stored file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `open()` function has an optional `encoding` parameter.
Its default is platform dependent, but in your case it apparently defaults to UTF-8.

I you know the correct codec (eg. from a HTTTP header), you can specify it:

```
html_doc = open('path/to/file.html', 'r', encoding='cp1252')
```

If you don't know it, chances are that it is written in the file.
You can open the file in binary mode:

```
html_doc = open('path/to/file.html', 'rb')
```

and then try to find an encoding declaration and decode the whole thing in memory.

However, don't do that.
There's not much use in opening and processing HTML like a text file.
You should use an HTML parser to walk through the document tree and extract whatever you need.
Python's standard library [has one](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html), but you might find [Beautiful Soup](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) easier to use.