# Convert unicode small capitals to their ASCII equivalents

Tags: python, unicode, ascii, python-unicode

I have the following dataset

```
'Fʀɪᴇɴᴅ',
 'ᴍᴏᴍ',
 'ᴍᴀᴋᴇs',
 'ʜᴏᴜʀʟʏ',
 'ᴛʜᴇ',
 'ᴄᴏᴍᴘᴜᴛᴇʀ',
 'ʙᴇᴇɴ',
 'ᴏᴜᴛ',
 'ᴀ',
 'ᴊᴏʙ',
 'ғᴏʀ',
 'ᴍᴏɴᴛʜs',
 'ʙᴜᴛ',
 'ʟᴀsᴛ',
 'ᴍᴏɴᴛʜ',
 'ʜᴇʀ',
 'ᴄʜᴇᴄᴋ',
 'ᴊᴜsᴛ',
 'ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ',
 'ғᴇᴡ',
 'ʜᴏᴜʀs',
 'sᴏᴜʀᴄᴇ',
```

I want then into ASCII format using Python script
for example:

```
Fʀɪᴇɴᴅ - FRIEND
ᴍᴏᴍ - MOM
```

I have tried encoding decoding but that doesn't work
i also have tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365411/convert-unicode-to-ascii-without-errors-in-python). but that doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: please show what you've tried

Comment: The link you provided is for an other problem. Try to look for normalization (module `unicodedata`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python doesn't provide a way to directly convert [small caps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_caps#Unicode) characters to their ASCII equivalents.  However it's possible to do this using [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate).

To use `str.translate` we need to create a mapping of small caps characters' ordinal values to ASCII characters.

To get the ordinal values, we can construct the name of each character, then get the character from the [unicodedata](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/unicodedata.html) database and call [ord](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) on it.  Note that there is no small caps 'X' character, and in Python versions before 3.7 small caps 'Q' is not present.

```
>>> from string import ascii_uppercase
>>> import unicodedata as ud

>>> # Filter out unsupported characters
>>> # Python < 3.7
>>> letters = (x for x in ascii_uppercase if x not in ('Q', 'X'))
>>> # Python >= 3.7
>>> letters = (x for x in ascii_uppercase if x != 'X') 

>>> mapping = {ord(ud.lookup('LATIN LETTER SMALL CAPITAL ' + x)): x for x in letters}
```

Once we have the mapping we can use it to make a translation table for `str.translate`, using [str.maketrans](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans), then perform the conversions.

```
>>> # Make as translation table
>>> tt = str.maketrans(mapping)
>>> # Use the table to "translate" strings to their ASCII equivalent.
>>> s = 'ᴍᴏɴᴛʜ'
>>> s.translate(tt)
'MONTH'
```

Comment: you almost solved my problem. but i am getting this error,
 KeyError: "undefined character name 'LATIN LETTER SMALL CAPITAL Q'"

Comment: @ArayanSingh  it seems Python versions prior to 3.7 don't include small caps 'Q' - presumably due to the version of the unicode database that they use.  Answer amended to take this into account.