# UnicodeEncodeError with character u'\u2013

Tags: python, ascii

I am receiving the below error with the dash character "-"

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 38: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have tried using the following: **skills.encode('utf-8')** but I still get the error. Below is my code in which I am trying to write to  csv.

```
 writer.writerow([name.encode('utf-8'),
                 heading.encode('utf-8'),
                 location.encode('utf-8'),
                 education.encode('utf-8'),
                 summary,
                 currentRole,
                 allRoles,
                 companiesFollowed,
                 groups,
                 skills.encode('utf-8')])
```

Comment: only you could say what that character is supposed to be.

Comment: The character is the dash

Comment: ah, not just a normal `-` dash, but an _n-dash_ https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm. Yeah you can't represent that in ASCII. What would you like to be there instead?

Comment: Just a regular dash if possible. I don't know the difference between a dash and an en dash.

Comment: if you use Python3 that's what you'll get (and you can skip the `encode`s). If you don't, you'll have to learn a whole lot more than you know now about Unicode and what a Unicode code point means. I'm not aware of any function that can just _know_ that you want an n-dash to be a hyphen. You could make your own string replacement using `string.maketrans` and `str.translate` but that's about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Unicode to ASCII without errors in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365411/convert-unicode-to-ascii-without-errors-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify one of a number of settings to `str.encode` under the `errors` keyword. More info can be found [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers) but I'd recommend you use the `'replace'` error handler.

```
writer.writerow([name.encode('utf-8', errors='replace'),
    heading.encode('utf-8', errors='replace'),
    location.encode('utf-8', errors='replace'),
    education.encode('utf-8', errors='replace'),
    summary,
    currentRole,
    allRoles,
    companiesFollowed,
    groups,
    skills.encode('utf-8', errors='replace')])
```

This will end up making a `bytes` object with a `?` in place of each unencodable code point.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Adam. That didnt work unfortunately I got this error  :
skills.encode('utf-8', errors='replace')])
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 38: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @dcraven I can't reproduce that result. What version of Python are you running?