# Turn special characters into ascii-like characters or someting else without losing readability

Tags: python, unicode, ascii

Trying to format data from ics calendar file to any outpu such as json or even python `print()`. Looking for good ways to replace special characters without losing readability and having ascii-like characters. Examples below. Any tips?

Summary field value in ics file

```
FORMULA 1 HEINEKEN GRANDE PRÉMIO DE PORTUGAL 2021 - Race
FORMULA 1 MYWORLD GROSSER PREIS VON ÖSTERREICH 2021 - Race
```

Summary key value in json file

```
FORMULA 1 HEINEKEN GRANDE PR\u00c3\u0089MIO DE PORTUGAL 2021 - Race
FORMULA 1 MYWORLD GROSSER PREIS VON \u00c3\u0096STERREICH 2021 - Race
```

Sample code to reproduce problem

```
import requests
import json
from icalendar import Calendar

## LOGIC HERE ##
def format_text(text):
    text = str(text)
    return text


url = "http://www.formula1.com/calendar/Formula_1_Official_Calendar.ics"
res = requests.get(url)
calendar = Calendar.from_ical(res.text)
events = [
    {
        "id": event["UID"].split("@")[-1].strip(),
        "startTime": event["DTSTART"].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3],
        "summary": format_text(event["SUMMARY"])
    } for event in calendar.walk("VEVENT") if str(event["UID"]).split("@")[0].startswith("Race")]


with open("events.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(events, f, indent=2)
```

Comment: You'll find something that suits your case perfectly here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7782177/14415205

Comment: One problem is in your example, you should use the binary content of the .ics file to pass to `from_ical`.  Use `res.content` instead of `res.text`.  The latter decodes the binary content incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data for the .ics file should not be decoded, but passed directly to `.from_ical`.  Use `res.content` instead.  Then `Calendar` generates the data decoded correctly as UTF-8 (probably part of the .ICS spec) and `print` can print Unicode strings correctly.  For the JSON, write with `utf8` encoding and `ensure_ascii=False` as @JosefZ recommended to see it correctly as well:

```py
import requests
import json
from icalendar import Calendar

url = 'http://www.formula1.com/calendar/Formula_1_Official_Calendar.ics'
res = requests.get(url)
calendar = Calendar.from_ical(res.content)
events = [
    {
        'id': event['UID'].split('@')[-1].strip(),
        'startTime': event['DTSTART'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3],
        'summary': event['SUMMARY']
    } for event in calendar.walk('VEVENT') if str(event['UID']).split('@')[0].startswith('Race')]

for event in events:
    print(event['summary'])

with open('events.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
    json.dump(events, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
```

`print` Output:

```
FORMULA 1 GULF AIR BAHRAIN GRAND PRIX 2021 - Race
FORMULA 1 PIRELLI GRAN PREMIO DEL MADE IN ITALY E DELL'EMILIA ROMAGNA 2021 - Race
FORMULA 1 HEINEKEN GRANDE PRÉMIO DE PORTUGAL 2021 - Race
FORMULA 1 ARAMCO GRAN PREMIO DE ESPAÑA 2021 - Race
FORMULA 1 GRAND PRIX DE MONACO 2021 - Race
FORMULA 1 AZERBAIJAN GRAND PRIX 2021 - Race
FORMULA 1 HEINEKEN GRAND PRIX DU CANADA 2021 - Race
FORMULA 1 EMIRATES GRAND PRIX DE FRANCE 2021 - Race
FORMULA 1 MYWORLD GROSSER PREIS VON ÖSTERREICH 2021 - Race
FORMULA 1 PIRELLI BRITISH GRAND PRIX 2021 - Race
FORMULA 1 MAGYAR NAGYDÍJ 2021 - Race
FORMULA 1 ROLEX BELGIAN GRAND PRIX 2021 - Race
FORMULA 1 HEINEKEN DUTCH GRAND PRIX 2021 - Race
FORMULA 1 HEINEKEN GRAN PREMIO D’ITALIA 2021 - Race
FORMULA 1 VTB RUSSIAN GRAND PRIX 2021 - Race
FORMULA 1 SINGAPORE AIRLINES SINGAPORE GRAND PRIX 2021 - Race
FORMULA 1 JAPANESE GRAND PRIX 2021 - Race
FORMULA 1 ARAMCO UNITED STATES GRAND PRIX 2021 - Race
FORMULA 1 GRAN PREMIO DE LA CIUDAD DE MÉXICO 2021 - Race
FORMULA 1 HEINEKEN GRANDE PRÊMIO DE SÃO PAULO 2021 - Race
FORMULA 1 ROLEX AUSTRALIAN GRAND PRIX 2021 - Race
FORMULA 1 SAUDI ARABIAN GRAND PRIX 2021 - Race
FORMULA 1 ETIHAD AIRWAYS ABU DHABI GRAND PRIX 2021 - Race
```

events.json:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "1064",
    "startTime": "2021-03-28T16:00:00.000",
    "summary": "FORMULA 1 GULF AIR BAHRAIN GRAND PRIX 2021 - Race"
  },
  {
    "id": "1065",
    "startTime": "2021-04-18T14:00:00.000",
    "summary": "FORMULA 1 PIRELLI GRAN PREMIO DEL MADE IN ITALY E DELL'EMILIA ROMAGNA 2021 - Race"
  },
  {
    "id": "1066",
    "startTime": "2021-05-02T15:00:00.000",
    "summary": "FORMULA 1 HEINEKEN GRANDE PRÉMIO DE PORTUGAL 2021 - Race"
  },
  {
    "id": "1086",
    "startTime": "2021-05-09T14:00:00.000",
    "summary": "FORMULA 1 ARAMCO GRAN PREMIO DE ESPAÑA 2021 - Race"
  },
  {
    "id": "1067",
    "startTime": "2021-05-23T14:00:00.000",
    "summary": "FORMULA 1 GRAND PRIX DE MONACO 2021 - Race"
  },
  {
    "id": "1068",
    "startTime": "2021-06-06T13:00:00.000",
    "summary": "FORMULA 1 AZERBAIJAN GRAND PRIX 2021 - Race"
  },
  {
    "id": "1069",
    "startTime": "2021-06-13T19:00:00.000",
    "summary": "FORMULA 1 HEINEKEN GRAND PRIX DU CANADA 2021 - Race"
  },
  {
    "id": "1070",
    "startTime": "2021-06-27T14:00:00.000",
    "summary": "FORMULA 1 EMIRATES GRAND PRIX DE FRANCE 2021 - Race"
  },
  {
    "id": "1071",
    "startTime": "2021-07-04T14:00:00.000",
    "summary": "FORMULA 1 MYWORLD GROSSER PREIS VON ÖSTERREICH 2021 - Race"
  },
  {
    "id": "1072",
    "startTime": "2021-07-18T15:00:00.000",
    "summary": "FORMULA 1 PIRELLI BRITISH GRAND PRIX 2021 - Race"
  },
  {
    "id": "1073",
    "startTime": "2021-08-01T14:00:00.000",
    "summary": "FORMULA 1 MAGYAR NAGYDÍJ 2021 - Race"
  },
  {
    "id": "1074",
    "startTime": "2021-08-29T14:00:00.000",
    "summary": "FORMULA 1 ROLEX BELGIAN GRAND PRIX 2021 - Race"
  },
  {
    "id": "1075",
    "startTime": "2021-09-05T14:00:00.000",
    "summary": "FORMULA 1 HEINEKEN DUTCH GRAND PRIX 2021 - Race"
  },
  {
    "id": "1076",
    "startTime": "2021-09-12T14:00:00.000",
    "summary": "FORMULA 1 HEINEKEN GRAN PREMIO D’ITALIA 2021 - Race"
  },
  {
    "id": "1077",
    "startTime": "2021-09-26T13:00:00.000",
    "summary": "FORMULA 1 VTB RUSSIAN GRAND PRIX 2021 - Race"
  },
  {
    "id": "1078",
    "startTime": "2021-10-03T13:00:00.000",
    "summary": "FORMULA 1 SINGAPORE AIRLINES SINGAPORE GRAND PRIX 2021 - Race"
  },
  {
    "id": "1079",
    "startTime": "2021-10-10T06:00:00.000",
    "summary": "FORMULA 1 JAPANESE GRAND PRIX 2021 - Race"
  },
  {
    "id": "1080",
    "startTime": "2021-10-24T20:00:00.000",
    "summary": "FORMULA 1 ARAMCO UNITED STATES GRAND PRIX 2021 - Race"
  },
  {
    "id": "1081",
    "startTime": "2021-10-31T19:00:00.000",
    "summary": "FORMULA 1 GRAN PREMIO DE LA CIUDAD DE MÉXICO 2021 - Race"
  },
  {
    "id": "1082",
    "startTime": "2021-11-07T17:00:00.000",
    "summary": "FORMULA 1 HEINEKEN GRANDE PRÊMIO DE SÃO PAULO 2021 - Race"
  },
  {
    "id": "1083",
    "startTime": "2021-11-21T06:00:00.000",
    "summary": "FORMULA 1 ROLEX AUSTRALIAN GRAND PRIX 2021 - Race"
  },
  {
    "id": "1085",
    "startTime": "2021-12-05T16:00:00.000",
    "summary": "FORMULA 1 SAUDI ARABIAN GRAND PRIX 2021 - Race"
  },
  {
    "id": "1084",
    "startTime": "2021-12-12T13:00:00.000",
    "summary": "FORMULA 1 ETIHAD AIRWAYS ABU DHABI GRAND PRIX 2021 - Race"
  }
]
```

Comment: Using content instead of text of response was the key thing here. Then with `unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", text).encode("ascii", "ignore")` I get rid off the special characters in nice way.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("events.json", mode="w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    json.dump(events, f, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
```

From [`json.dump` *docs*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump):

> If `ensure_ascii` is true (the default), the output is guaranteed to
> have all incoming non-ASCII characters escaped. **If `ensure_ascii` is
> false, these characters will be output as-is.**

Used `encoding="utf-8"` in `open` as the [**default encoding is platform dependent** (whatever `locale.getpreferredencoding()` returns)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

Comment: I don't want to rely on json output only.

Comment: Follow the [comment by @MarkTolonen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67425612/turn-special-characters-into-ascii-like-characters-or-someting-else-without-losi/67425847?noredirect=1#comment119202037_67425612) and use `res.content` instead of `res.text`.