# importing csv file using pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, import

I am trying to import a csv file using pandas in python but it is showing me the following error:
##code## Companies = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\salsa\Downloads\1000_Companies.csv')

output: SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

I tried the double slashes, forward slashes and putting 'r' at the front. nothing seems to work. Can anyone help me with this?

thank you

Comment: using a raw string (putting "r" in front) definitely doesn't result in a syntax error. what exactly did you do?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347791/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-cannot-open-text-file?noredirect=1&lq=1) is what you are looking for.
Instead of an 'r', put a 'u' in the front of the string.

Other possible solutions:

Can you open the csv with an editor and show the control characters to provide an example of the csv?

If using notepad++ open the csv file then:
view->show symbol-> show all characters
do a screenshot around position 2-3 and send it here.

It smells as ascii/unicode problem.
if you can and do not lose important features of your dataset, try to convert the csv to ascii, [here an example on how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2365444/21305291)
otherwise.

Comment: The issue is absolutely not the dataset. The issue is the Python source code, hence the SyntaxError, the Python code *doesn't even compile*.

Answer (score 0):

try checking with the following replacement:

```
    import csv
    Companies= open(r 'C:\Users\salsa\Downloads\1000_Companies.csv')
    Companies= csv.reader(Companies)
```

If this is working perfectly then you might have error syntax of the code.

if none are working try this, but cant promise anything. but might worth checking.

```
    import os
    import pandas as pd
    Companies= "C:\Users\salsa\Downloads\1000_Companies.csv"
    pwd = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(os.path.dirname(Companies))
    Companies= pd.read_csv(os.path.basename(Companies))
    os.chdir(pwd)
```

Comment: Double quotes are irrelevant. You already showed one solution

Comment: thanks for the comment. hope the remaining are releveant. if not plz leave us a correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this, it must be working

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\iffy\Desktop\filename.csv')
```