# How to replace unicode characters by ascii characters in Python (perl script given)?

Tags: python, perl, unicode, diacritics

I am trying to learn python and couldn't figure out how to translate the following perl script to python:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w                     

use open qw(:std :utf8);

while(<>) {
  s/\x{00E4}/ae/;
  s/\x{00F6}/oe/;
  s/\x{00FC}/ue/;
  print;
}
```

The script just changes unicode umlauts to alternative ascii output. (So the complete output is in ascii.) I would be grateful for any hints. Thanks!

Comment: search SO for "transliteration" to find related questions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/816285/where-is-pythons-best-ascii-for-this-unicode-database/816319#816319

Comment: The given Perl script will actually only substitute the first occurrence on each line, but that's surely an accident.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- Use the [`fileinput`](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html) module to loop over standard input or a list of files,
- decode the lines you read from UTF-8 to unicode objects
- then map any unicode characters you desire with the [`translate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) method

`translit.py` would look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.6
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import fileinput

table = {
          0xe4: u'ae',
          ord(u'ö'): u'oe',
          ord(u'ü'): u'ue',
          ord(u'ß'): None,
        }

for line in fileinput.input():
    s = line.decode('utf8')
    print s.translate(table),
```

And you could use it like this:

```
$ cat utf8.txt 
sömé täßt
sömé täßt
sömé täßt

$ ./translit.py utf8.txt 
soemé taet
soemé taet
soemé taet
```

- ***Update:***

In case you are using python 3 strings are by default unicode and you dont' need to encode it if it contains non-ASCII characters or even a non-Latin characters. So the solution will look as follow:

```py
line = 'Verhältnismäßigkeit, Möglichkeit'

table = {
         ord('ä'): 'ae',
         ord('ö'): 'oe',
         ord('ü'): 'ue',
         ord('ß'): 'ss',
       }

line.translate(table)

>>> 'Verhaeltnismaessigkeit, Moeglichkeit'
```

Comment: And to get ascii output the last line should be `print s.translate(table).encode('ascii', 'ignore')`, I guess.

Comment: strictly speaking the original .pl doesn't do that either, but yes, that would be one solution

Comment: The objective appears to be de-umlauting German text, leaving it understandable. The effect of `ord(u'ß'): None` in 
this code is to **delete** the ß ("eszett") character. It should be `ord(u'ß'): u'ss'`. Upvotes?? Accepted answer???

Comment: oh. come. on. i tried to show the different possibilities for the map.

Comment: You chose a very bad example of how to do something that the OP didn't indicate that he wanted or needed.

Comment: @john: if you would take the OP's question literally together with his comment above ('ignore'), it would have the _exact_ _same_ outcome, so stop nitpicking already.

Comment: Is there no library that can do this for us?

Comment: @PascalvKooten: there are several, search for "unicode" on pypi. try `unidecode` for example. it has the same problem of stripping `ö` down to `o`, etc.

Answer (score 48):

For converting to ASCII you might want to try [ASCII, Dammit](http://www.crummy.com/cgi-bin/msm/map.cgi/ASCII,+Dammit) or [this recipe](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/unicode-to-ascii), which boils down to:

```
>>> title = u"Klüft skräms inför på fédéral électoral große"
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', title).encode('ascii','ignore')
'Kluft skrams infor pa federal electoral groe'
```

Comment: which does not at all what the original .pl does (mainly properly transliterating german special characters)

Comment: stripping the dots from german umlauts makes just about as much sense as stripping one leg from "x" and writing "y" or replacing "d" with "b" because the "kinda look the same".

Comment: No, you might get collisions because you map different strings to the same one.

Answer (score 7):

You could try [`unidecode`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) to convert Unicode into ascii instead of writing manual regular expressions. It is a Python port of `Text::Unidecode` Perl module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import fileinput
import locale
from contextlib import closing
from unidecode import unidecode # $ pip install unidecode

def toascii(files=None, encoding=None, bufsize=-1):
    if encoding is None:
        encoding = locale.getpreferredencoding(False)
    with closing(fileinput.FileInput(files=files, bufsize=bufsize)) as file:
        for line in file: 
            print unidecode(line.decode(encoding)),

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    toascii(encoding=sys.argv.pop(1) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else None)
```

It uses `FileInput` class to avoid global state.

Example:

```
$ echo 'äöüß' | python toascii.py utf-8
aouss
```

Answer (score 3):

I use [translitcodec](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/translitcodec/0.1)

```
>>> import translitcodec
>>> print '\xe4'.decode('latin-1')
ä
>>> print '\xe4'.decode('latin-1').encode('translit/long').encode('ascii')
ae
>>> print '\xe4'.decode('latin-1').encode('translit/short').encode('ascii')
a
```

You can change the decode language to whatever you need. You may want a simple function to reduce length of a single implementation.

```
def fancy2ascii(s):
    return s.decode('latin-1').encode('translit/long').encode('ascii')
```

Answer (score -3):

Quick and dirty (python2):

```
def make_ascii(string):
    return string.decode('utf-8').replace(u'ü','ue').replace(u'ö','oe').replace(u'ä','ae').replace(u'ß','ss').encode('ascii','ignore');
```