# Replace the special characters with the near matching type-able characters

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, special-characters, apostrophe

I would like to replace all the special characters such as apostrophe(not single quote), double quote and any other characters(which looks differently on ms word) with single quote, double quote **but not limited only these two**.

I may replace it by manually using regex or string's replace by finding the unicode value of these characters like `re.sub("\u0XXXX", "'", "<apostrophe>")`

But I believe there may be a built in function which will replace if there is a exact match and keep as is if it does not have like in PHP `iconv("ISO-XXX", "UTF-8//TRANSLIT//IGNORE")`.

```
eg: ’ to ', ˮ - " any such characters
```

Comment: Does this answer help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2701901/3336968

Comment: But I wanted to keep those mentioned characters as is.