# Python: How to remove the majority of special unicode chars but leave accents and mutated vowels intact?

Tags: python, unicode, non-ascii-characters

I am scraping text from a webpage in Python.

The text contains all kinds of special unicode chars such as hearts, smilies and other wild stuff.

By using `content.encode('ascii', 'ignore')` I am able to convert everything to ASCII but that means all accented chars and mutated vowels such as 'ä' or 'ß' are gone as well.

How can leave the "normal" chars such as 'ä' or 'é' intact but can remove all the other stuff?

(I must admit I am quite a newbie in Python and I never really got behind all the magic behind character encoding).

Comment: Can you provide an example input and expected output and also show what you tried so far.

Comment: Why can't you use unicode?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace unicode characters by ascii characters in Python (perl script given)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700859/how-to-replace-unicode-characters-by-ascii-characters-in-python-perl-script-giv)

Comment: `content.encode('latin1','ignore')` will keep the common Western European accented characters.  You'll still lose Russian, Japanese, Chinese, etc.

Comment: @cwallenpoole: I would like to create a wordcloud in R later in that process and don't want all these wild characters.

Comment: @MarkTolonen with 'latin1' now I get something like `N\xe4gel`where it should be `Nägel`(German word for 'nails')

Comment: @LeftyGBalogh something like this: `# create translation map for non-bmp charactes
non_bmp_map = dict.fromkeys(range(0x10000, sys.maxunicode + 1), 0xfffd)

question = "Magst du Nägel?"

fileQuestions = open (filenameQuestions, "w", encoding='utf-8')
fileQuestions.write("{}\n".format(question.encode('ascii', 'ignore')))` gives me `'Magst du Ngel?"` but I would like to keep the 'ä' but not the smiley.

Comment: Jesus... how can I add line breaks in comments?

Comment: @JörgF. you can't. Edit your question instead of creating illegible comments.

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3? In the former case, `u'N\xe4gel'` is exactly what you want.

Comment: You mean `'N\xe4gel'` (with quotes)?.  That's a debug representation.  `print('N\xe4gel')` will display correctly.  Python 2 only shows ASCII in a debug representation and escape codes for non-ASCII.  See `repr()` vs. `str()`.  Switch to Python 3 and it will display debug representations with non-ASCII as well, and `ascii()` can be used for the old presentation.

Comment: Technically, my last comment about print will only work on a terminal configured for latin1.  Use `sys.stdout.encoding` or decode the latin1 byte string back to Unicode before printing in Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear from your question where you draw the line between the “good” and the “bad” characters, but you probably don't know that yet, either.
Unicode contains a lot of different kinds of characters, and you might not be aware of the diversity.

Unicode assigns a [category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property#General_Category) to each character, such as “Letter, lowercase” or “Punctuation, final quote” or “Symbol, other”.
Python's std-lib module `unicodedata` gives you convenient access to this information:

```
>>> import unicodedata as ud
>>> ud.category('ä')
'Ll'
>>> ud.category('')
'So'
```

From your examples it seems like you think *letters* are good, while *symbols* are bad.
But you'll have to sort out the rest too.
You probably want to keep blanks (“separators”) and punctuation as well.
And you *might* need the marks too, as they include the [combining characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character).

Answer (score 0):

Few steps:

You should normalize unicode, with `unicodedata.normalize('NFC', my_text)`. Not really on the question, but you must have a common ground, let's have the same character to have the same encoding.

Then you should check every character to see if you allow it or not:

```
new_text = []
for c in my_normalized_text:
    if ord(c) < 128:
        # this is optional, it add ascii character as they are
        # possibly you want to tokenize (see later, how we replace punctuation)
        new_text.append(c)
        continue
    cat = unicodedata.category(c)
    if cat in {'Lu', 'Ll', 'Lt', 'Lm', 'Lo', 'Nd'}:
        new_text.append(c)
    elif cat in {'Mc', 'Pc', 'Pd', 'Ps', 'Pe', 'Pi', 'Of', 'Po', 'Zs', 'Zl', 'Zp'}:
        # this tokenize
        new_text.append(' ')
    # else: do not append. You may still append ' ' and remove above check.
```

You should adapt according your next processing methods: See [Python Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html) and the linked page [Unicode character categories](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#General_Category_Values).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally used this:

```
    # create translation map for non-bmp charactes
    non_bmp_map = dict.fromkeys(range(0x10000, sys.maxunicode + 1), 0xfffd)

    # strip unwanted unicode images
    question = question.translate(non_bmp_map)

    # convert to latin-1 to remove all stupid unicode characters
    # you may want to adapt this to your personal needs
    #
    # for some strange reason I have to first transform the string to bytes with latin-1
    # encoding and then do the reverse transform from bytes to string with latin-1 encoding as
    # well... maybe has to be revised later
    bQuestion = question.encode('latin-1', 'ignore')
    question = bQuestion.decode('latin-1', 'ignore')
```

Thanks to anybody who answered