# How to convert non-ASCII in filename

Tags: python

I have a film title like so:

```
México
```

How would I convert this into a cleaned filename?

```
Mexico
```

Basically, I need to remove all non-ASCII characters from a name and replace it with its normalized character.

```
MéNnñø --> Menno
```

Comment: possible Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207457/convert-unicode-to-string-in-python-containing-extra-symbols, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/816285/where-is-pythons-best-ascii-for-this-unicode-database