# HTML Unescape by converting custom elements to ASCII?

Tags: python, unicode, escaping

I need to unescape some HTML Entities from a string.

However for few characters like `&ldquo;&rsquo;&ldquo;&rdquo;'` I would like to replace with nearest ASCII. All the others needs to be stripped off.

How can I do that in Python ? I tried the following snippet but it doesn't do "nearest" the way I want it.

```
import HTMLParser
import unicodedata
parser = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
parsed = parser.unescape("&lsquo;")
nearest = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', parsed).encode('ascii','ignore')
```

`nearest` is empty in the above code. Can I supply an argument to HTMLParser.unescape to convert it to ASCII quotes? I want to supply  custom mapping like this : {'&lsquo':'"','&rsquo':'"'} where the items in maps should be converted to ASCII.

`xml.sax.parse` has some an API `unescape(html_text, entities={'&nbsp;': ' ', "&quot;": '"'})`, does HTMLParser have something similar.

Comment: Rather than map the HTML entity, why not use [`unidecode`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) here? It'll map quotes to ASCII equivalents for you.

Comment: So you mean use a 3rd party library I was hesistant to do that if we had some stdlib solution. Thanks for the pointer however as its something worth checking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is Python's "best ASCII for this Unicode" database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/816285/where-is-pythons-best-ascii-for-this-unicode-database)