# ASCII error when fetching results from database with pyodbc and sql server 2005

Tags: python, sql-server-2005

I have this error when fetching results from the database.

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf1' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)`

Upon closer inspection, I found out that several of the records have ñ and Ñ in them. And I cannot just replace them or ignore them because my db are records for personal information and cannot be changed. I have read many links regarding this and most of it says that I have to replace them or remove them. I have also tried using what's [in here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) but it's not applicable when database is involve. Also, I tried this [one](http://blog.webforefront.com/archives/2011/02/python_ascii_co.html), and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1701378/4652234) but nothing seems to answer my problem. I am formatting the fetched results like this:

```
cursor.execute("select * from dummy")
str1=''
for row in cursor:
    str1 = str1 + ''.join(map(str,row)) + "\n" 
print str1
```

and it outputs the error above.
However, when I try this one:

```
for row in cursor:
    str1 = str(row)
    print str1.decode('latin-1')
```

It display NO errors but the results were:

```
(u'Ara\xf1as    ', )
(u'Para\xf1aque ', )
(u'Ma\xf1a\xf1a    ', )
(u'Di\xd1a      ', )
```

instead of

```
Arañas
Parañaque
Mañaña
DiÑa
```

How can I solve this ascii error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cast the whole row to string.
Try something like:

```
print row[0]
print str(row[0])
print row[0].encode('latin-1')
print row[0].encode('utf-8')
```

That will bring you closer to your solution.

Comment: Hi there! thank you for replying! What if I have several columns?

Comment: row[0], row[1], ... your row is just a python-tuple.

Comment: I have thought about that but it will not be very practical to my situation since I have more than 80 columns..

Comment: Ok, let's solve your encoding problem first. Getting the columns by name is another thing.

Comment: The one that worked for me was the first one. Decode got an error.

Comment: Nope. I tried it and well, the first one is still better. The print row[0].