# Exporting data to a CSV file, error can't encode character '\xe8'

Tags: python, csv

I have a large set of data and I am going to export them into a CSV file using the following code.

```
 with open ('/Users/mz/Dropbox/dis/Programming/zoloft.csv',
            'w', newline = '') as zolo:
        zolo = csv.writer(zolo, delimiter =',', quotechar='|')


        rows = zip(all_rating, all_disorders, all_side_effects,
                   all_comments, all_gender, all_age, all_dosage_duration, all_date)

        for row in rows:       
            zolo.writerow(row)
```

But there is the following error:

```
   zolo.writerow(row)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe8' in position 179: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is there any way to handle this error inside the code I wrote? Thanks !

Comment: Looks like somebody's name or comment has a [foreign-accented character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e8/index.htm) in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`csv` module, at present, doesn't have Unicode support](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), but your dataset clearly contains Unicode characters. So what you can do is something similar to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816285/where-is-pythons-best-ascii-for-this-unicode-database), and translate the Unicode characters to their nearest ASCII equivalents (so your text isn't illegible later).

I'd go with something like:

```
from unidecode import unidecode
with open('file', 'w', newline = '') as zolo:
    zolo = csv.writer(zolo, delimiter =',', quotechar='|')

    rows = zip(all_rating, all_disorders, all_side_effects,
               all_comments, all_gender, all_age,
               all_dosage_duration, all_date)

    for row in rows:       
        zolo.writerow(map(unidecode, row))
```

Comment: thank you ! there is still the following error: ' File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/unidecode/__init__.py", line 48, in unidecode_expect_ascii
    bytestring = string.encode('ASCII')
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'', can you help me with that ?

Comment: thank you !,  I tried it. The output is just column of some letters (such as 'o', 'l', 'k') it seems it removed all the information and just kept some letters.

Comment: @ Sebastian Lenartowicz,  Thank you !