# Getting python string equivalence to work like SQL match

Tags: python

I am trying to match two strings, `Serhat Kılıç` and `serhat kilic`. In SQL this is quite easy, as I can do:

```
select name from main_creditperson where name = 'serhat kılıç'
union all
select name from main_creditperson where name = 'serhat kilic';

===
name
Serhat Kılıç
Serhat Kılıç
```

In other words, both names return the same result. How would I do a string equivalent in python to see that these two names are 'the same' in the SQL sense. I am looking to do something like:

```
if name1 == name2:
   do_something()
```

I tried going the `unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', input_str)` way but it wasn't getting me anywhere. How would I solve this?

Comment: Also, behaviour of the SQL query would be very implementation-dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're OK with ASCII for everything, you can check [Where is Python's "best ASCII for this Unicode" database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816285/where-is-pythons-best-ascii-for-this-unicode-database) [`Unidecode`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) is rather good, however it is GPL-licensed which might be a problem for some project. Anyway, it would work in your case and in quite a many others, and works on Python 2 and 3 alike (these are from Python 3 so that it is easier to see what's going in):

```
>>> from unidecode import unidecode
>>> unidecode('serhat kılıç')
'serhat kilic'
>>> unidecode('serhat kilic')
'serhat kilic'
>>> # as a bonus it does much more, like
>>> unidecode('北亰')
'Bei Jing '
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this

```
def compare_words (str_1, str_2):
    return unidecode(str_1.decode('utf-8')) == str_2
```

Tested on Python 2.7:

```
In[2]: from unidecode import unidecode
In[3]: def compare_words (str_1, str_2):
     return unidecode(str_1.decode('utf-8')) == str_2
 In[4]: print compare_words('serhat kılıç', 'serhat kilic')
 True
```

Comment: I already tried that approach. It doesn't work: `>>> remove_accents(u'serhat kılıç')==remove_accents(u'serhat kilic')
False`. Note that I'm not looking to remove accents the "i" character is not an accent.