# Spreadsheet Compare (Office 2013) automation from .NET application or VSTO add-in

Tags: excel, vsto

Is it possible to automate the new [Spreadsheet Compare](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/support/basic-tasks-in-spreadsheet-compare-HA102834117.aspx) tool of Office 2013 from a .NET application or a VSTO Excel add-in by embedding some Microsoft assemblies?

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702663/how-to-script-excel-2013s-spreadsheet-compare) was asked for VBA programming and the response was no.

I managed to execute the application "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\DCF\SPREADSHEETCOMPARE.EXE" in command-line with a text file as input argument containing two workbooks paths in separate lines, but it would be easier to call a method directly from the code, as for the other functions of Excel.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a simple batch script that allows compare of two files from a command line.
Please refer to github: https://github.com/kniklas/excomp for further details.

I hope it will help those who would like to automate process of excel comparison (e.g. to hook this for version control - diff - of excel files).

Answer (score 1):

A sample code on how this could be implemented can be found at:

[Calling SpreadsheetCompare from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702663/how-to-script-excel-2013s-spreadsheet-compare/35905262#35905262)

Comment: It would be better always brief the solution within the answer. Links can be changed/removed at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, these workarounds will not work if your spreadsheets are maintained in TFS and you want to configure SpreadsheetCompare.exe as a user tool.

Configuring the tool to be used for Compare requires that both filenames be passed in as command line arguments.

Comment: Actually, I take this back.  If I create a batch script as noted above and configure it as the tool, then I can use TFS to compare two versions of a spreadsheet