# How can we use Git for a project having More Excel sheets

Tags: git

Can Git Work with Excel sheets.
Can we see the changes we made in the in the Excel sheet once it is commited as we can see in the text documents In GIT repository.

Comment: Can you commit any type of file, including binaries to a git repository? Yes, absolutely? Can I conveniently compare them? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114698/how-do-i-create-a-proper-diff-of-two-spreadsheets-when-i-perform-a-version-contr

Comment: You can git any repository (basically, any folder)

Comment: I don't think Git will be useful for handling Excel sheets, which I suppose can be considered a type of binary.  But can Git handle Excel sheets?  Absolutely, it can.