# Unzip - how do I put inflated files into an array

Tags: xml, git, bash, diff, unzip

I have an .xls file which I want to pretty print in order to have nice diffing rather than just binary files being changed.

My approach is to `unzip` this entire thing. The resulting string does not contain linebreaks so I ran it through `xmllint --format`. But on this seemingly simple path I have encountered several issues which I have already spent hours on:

1. `unzip` multiple files inside the xml archive. This results in invalid xml. Even with `unzip -q` options I get multiple DTDs and so on. xmllint breaks on this without formatting the input.

   `unzip -c -a -q myFile.xlsx | xmllint --format -`
2. I tried splitting the XML into an array using `read` in order to feed each individual xml file to xmllint. In the result of `read` most array items seem to be empty and the third and fourth item contain 20something letters of the xml string.

   `IFS='\<\?xml' read -r -a files <<< "$decompressed"`
3. I also tried just inserting linebreaks with `sed` but the filesize is so large that processing takes too long for making it feasible for diffing.

   `${decompressed/\>\</\>\n\</g}`

I have just run out of ideas so I decided to consult you guys! Thanks ahead :)

Comment: Beware the XY problem. Maybe take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114698/how-do-i-create-a-readable-diff-of-two-spreadsheets-using-git-diff?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: I added the code.

Comment: @FranzSkuffka I would unpack them into folders and then recursively diff them. Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would extract the xslx into multiple files, pretty-print them and then do a recursive diff on the xml files. (there are also binary files that can't be diffed)

Like this:

```
# Unzip the xlsx files into folders
unzip -aqd foo foo.xlsx
unzip -aqd bar bar.xlsx

# Pretty print all .xml and .rels files
find foo bar \( -name '*.xml' -o -name '*.rels' \) -exec xmllint --format {} --output {} \;

# Now you can recursively diff them
diff -urN foo bar
```

You can create bash function that wraps the process.

Note: The unpacked xlsx file may contain binary files with `.bin` ending. You need to exclude them from diff:

```
diff -urNx '*.bin' foo bar
```

Comment: Glad to see that it helps

Comment: Did you receive my mail?

Answer (score 1):

As you already found out, the XLSX file contains more than one XML file, as specified in the [official documentation](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm). In particular, there will be one XML document per Excel sheet, which means just combining them will not be a practical solution.

To make matters worse, you might also have a [shared string table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278314.aspx) in Excel files, which means the sheet files themselves will not contain the original strings ("Hello, World!"), but instead just a reference to the string table (1234).

Depending on your use case, you may want to consider more text-based formats like [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).

Comment: Thank you for the information. Appreciated, yet not the solution I am looking for.