# Is there a way to do a git diff on a column-by-column rather than line-by-line basis?

Tags: git, github, diff, git-diff

I have a lot of files in various git repos. Most of them (unsurprisingly) are code files. Many are data files. These may be CSV or TSV or similar.

If I make a change to a line in a data file then git diff works nicely - it shows me that I've changed that one line.

If I add a column it tells me that I've changed every line - which is completely useless.

e.g. I create a data file

```
18:59:39:~/example (main~) $ cat > test.tsv
Apples  10
Bananas 20
Carrots 5
Durian  0
19:00:57:~/example (main~) $ git add test.tsv 
19:01:04:~/example (main~) $ git commit -a -m 'add fruit & veg'
[main (root-commit) a958d8e] add fruit & veg
 1 file changed, 4 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 test.tsv
```

Now I add a line:

```
19:01:23:~/example (main~) $ cat >> test.tsv << EOF
> eggplant  8
> EOF
19:02:22:~/example (main~) $ git diff
diff --git a/test.tsv b/test.tsv
index 33c1ad1..7838c0f 100644
--- a/test.tsv
+++ b/test.tsv
@@ -2,3 +2,4 @@ Apples  10
 Bananas    20
 Carrots    5
 Durian 0
+eggplant   8
```

This is great - I can see a change and easily verify it that it affects just my one new row. Being good, I commit it.

```
19:02:26:~/example (main~) $ git commit -a -m 'add eggplant'
[main 54d76ee] add eggplant
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

Now I add a column:

```
19:02:46:~/example (main~) $ sed -i 's/$/\t0/g' test.tsv
```

Now I diff:

```
19:03:33:~/example (main~) $ git diff .
diff --git a/test.tsv b/test.tsv
index 7838c0f..47119f8 100644
--- a/test.tsv
+++ b/test.tsv
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
-Apples 10
-Bananas    20
-Carrots    5
-Durian 0
-eggplant   8
+Apples 10  0
+Bananas    20  0
+Carrots    5   0
+Durian 0   0
+eggplant   8   0
19:03:36:~/example (main~) $
```

This just tells me that there are changes to every line. How do I tell at a glance that this is just in the one column that I've added and not inadvertently knocked something else?

Similarly, how do I put it into a github PR and make it equally obvious to the next guy to look at this?

Obviously this isn't a big issue in my 5 line example - the real question is how would I do that in a 100+ line real world use case.

Comment: Text files are inherently line-oriented (they are *defined* in POSIX as lines of text). A new column really is just additional text added to multiple lines in the file.

Comment: Easiest is probably `git diff --word-diff-regex='[^\t]*'` on that file, that will highlight just the words that have changed and define a word as a sequence of non-tabs, so you'll see the added column in green.

Comment: The short answer is no, Git won't do that. To achieve what you want, consider doing a transposition (swap lines and columns by creating two *new* files). Now a line-by-line diff *is* a column-by-column diff. You may wish to do this with tooling other than Git (e.g., with Python's difference engine) so that you can transform back for display purposes, which would be agonizing when using Git's output.

Comment: Once you *are* using some other difference engine, it may become trivial to do this as a column-by-column diff, simply by making each column the symbol and doing the indexing in the transposed manner. Remember that diff in general is a string-to-string edit minimization solver (for more on this see [what's currently chapter 3 in my proto-book](http://web.torek.net/torek/tmp/book.pdf)).

Comment: There is a library called [daff](https://github.com/paulfitz/daff/) which is mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252280/2166823) and might be helpful (although I had some issues running it personally)